# Why is the culture name for English (Caribbean) "en-029"?

Tags: c#, .net, culture, cultureinfo

Why is the [culture name](http://www.csharp-examples.net/culture-names/) for English (Caribbean) "en-029"?

I know "en-CA" is used for English (Canada), but why 029? What does it signify? Why was it chosen?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Michael Kaplan (aka Microsoft's Unicode guru) [just wrote a blog post](http://www.siao2.com/2011/08/16/10196054.aspx) about that last week.

**EDIT**

And actually, if you read the comments you'll see that `029` isn't even an ISO 3166 code because ISO 3166 is only about countries. That's where [UN M.49](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UN_M.49) comes in which defines codes that specify:

> a wide variety of geographical, political, or economic regions, like a
>   continent, a country, or a specific “group of developing countries”.

And that's where you get code `029` for Caribbean.

Comment: What are the odds? (Maybe he wrote the post after seeing this question, but changed the date? ;-)) Thanks for the info!

Comment: I couldn't believe it either! In another week I might have forgotten about it.

Answer (score 0):

It might have something to do with [country area codes assigned by United Nations](http://unstats.un.org/unsd/methods/m49/m49regin.htm).
I might be wrong but I believe there is more than one country in the Caribbean area, therefore MS decided to assign the territory code rather than specific symbol (the latter probably is not registered).