# Display the tomorrow's date

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to create a JS code which displays tthe tomorrow's date.
This is the code I tried :

```
var d = new Date.today().addDays(1).toString("dd-mm-yyyy");
```

but it won't work for me.

How can I solve it ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [JavaScript how to get tomorrows date in format dd-mm-yy](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9444745/javascript-how-to-get-tomorrows-date-in-format-dd-mm-yy)

Comment: Check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9444745/javascript-how-to-get-tomorrows-date-in-format-dd-mm-yy

Answer (score 7):

```
var todayDate = new Date();

todayDate .setDate(todayDate .getDate() + 1);
```

Then `todayDate`  contains tomorrow date

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
var d = new Date();
var tomorrowDate = d.getDate() + 1;
d.setDate(tomorrowDate);
document.write("Tommorow date : " + d );
```

Output :

> Tommorow date : Fri Jul 05 2013 19:16:50 GMT+0530 (IST)

Answer (score 0):

```
var d = new Date();
d.setDate(d.getDate() + 1)
console.log(d)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're going to deal a lot with dates, I'd recommend you to use [Moment.js](http://momentjs.com). It allows you to do exactly what you want, aswell much more things:

```
var date = moment().add("days", 1);
// If displaying this date, use the following to format it in your culture.
// Will be mm-dd-yyyy in en-US, I believe
date.format("L");
```

Docs: http://momentjs.com/docs/

Comment: maybe you mean `moment().add(1, 'days')`  ?