# get tomorrows date with jquery and compare

Tags: javascript, jquery, date, datetime

how is it possble to get the date in this format ? 28/09/2013

what i am getting now is,

```
Fri Sep 27 2013 15:19:01 GMT+0530 (Sri Lanka Standard Time)
```

This is the code i have written to get that..

```
 var date = new Date();
 var tomorrow = new Date(date.getTime() + 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000);
 alert(tomorrow);
```

and i need to see weather, is the given date is tomorrow. something like this when i give 28/09/2013 it should alert as tomorrow or not.

any help is highlight appreciated.

NOTE : i only need to compare with date. 28/09/2013 === tomorrow

Comment: Comparing dates in JS is a nightmare. Use [date.js](http://www.datejs.com/) to simplify it.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan ok. but how to get only date from this ? Fri Sep 27 2013 15:19:01 GMT+0530 (Sri Lanka Standard Time)

Comment: Why would you want to use jquery, a dom manipulation library, to compare dates

Comment: @mazraara check on the documentation of date.js, specifically the `toString()` method.

Comment: @Lepidosteus is there any other possibility ?

Comment: @mazraara the Date() object is not part of jquery. It's javascript. There is not a single word in your question that is jquery specific. Jquery is a javascript library for dom manipulation (adding a div, changing the color of an element, ...). I recommend you read a good javascript documentation to avoid mixing the two together.

Comment: @Lepidosteus tnx a lot. btw do u knw hw can i check weather two dates are equal or not via javascript?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would use the ***[DateJS library](http://www.datejs.com/)***.

```
var tomorrow = new Date.today().addDays(1).toString("dd-mm-yyyy");
```

Comment: You probably should add a note in your answer that this is using date.js, not methods available to the native date type.

Comment: Yes. Solution modified ;)

Comment: @Nadeem_MK do i need to have date.js included in the page to do this or can use straight forward inside a <script></script> tag?

Comment: `<script type="text/javascript" src="date.js"></script>`

Answer (score 8):

You can try following to get the next day :

```
var myDate=new Date();
myDate.setDate(myDate.getDate()+1);
// format a date
var dt = myDate.getDate() + '/' + ("0" + (myDate.getMonth() + 1)).slice(-2) + '/' + myDate.getFullYear();
console.log(dt);
```

Here is the demo : http://jsfiddle.net/5Yj3V/3/

Comment: will it work on a situation like this ? lets say today is the last day of month of September if i take tomrrow will it print 30 or October 1st ?

Comment: yes, it will. It will return you October 1st. Infact you can try it, change the difference to 5 and check. Here is the [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/5Yj3V/1/)

Comment: there is a problem... the month is returning as one digit so this causes a mismatch... 28/09/2013 --- 27/9/2013.. it should be 09 not just 9.

Comment: @mazraara:   updated fiddle and answer as you want. Use : `("0" + (myDate.getMonth() + 1)).slice(-2)` it'll give month in 2-digit format

Answer (score 6):

[Moment.js](http://momentjs.com/) will do that for you very easily.

```
moment().add('days', 1).format('L');
```

Answer (score 1):

Try the below [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/saranyaciet/9Q6B3/1/) using javascript.

```
var tomorrow = new Date(); 
var newdate = new Date();
var month = (newdate.getMonth()+1);
newdate.setDate(tomorrow.getDate() + 1);
if (month < 10)
{
    month = '0' + (newdate.getMonth()+1);
}

alert(newdate);
alert(newdate.getDate() + '/' + month + '/' + newdate.getFullYear());
```

Comment: will it work on a situation like this ? lets say today is the last day of month of September if i take tomrrow will it print 30 or October 1st ?

Comment: Since getMonth() returns 0-11,you'll have to increment the value by 1 i.e. `newdate.getMonth()+1`

Comment: @SaranyaSadhasivam there is a problem... the month is returning as one digit so this causes a mismatch... 28/09/2013 --- 27/9/2013.. it should be 09 not just 9.