# How to add days to date using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have input text like below:

```js
$('#term').change(function() {
  var ll = $(this).val();
  var bb = $('#date').val();
  var date = new Date(bb);
  var newDate = new Date(date);
  newDate.setDate(newDate.getDate() + parseInt(ll));
  var dd = newDate.getDate();
  var mm = newDate.getMonth() + 1;
  var y = newDate.getFullYear();
  var someFormattedDate = dd + '-' + mm + '-' + y;
  $('#due_date').val(someFormattedDate);
});
```

```css
div {
  margin: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="form-group">
  <label for="date">Date:</label>
  <input id="invodate" type="text" id="date" class="form-control" name="date" value="" style="width: 150px;">
</div>
<div class="form-group">
  <label for="term">Term:</label>
  <input type="text" class="form-control" id="term" name="term" value="" style="width: 50px;">
</div>
<div class="form-group">
  <label for="due_date">Due Date:</label>
  <input type="text" class="form-control" id="due_date" name="due_date" value="" style="width: 150px;">
</div>
```

I wanna give days to `input #term` and then on Due Date in input show date, but in my code show `NaN-NaN-NaN` only. What error with my code. thank for answer.

Comment: `moment(date).add( 2, "days" ).format("YYYY/MM/DD")` :) Check out moment.js

Comment: why do you have `date` and `newDate` ?

Answer (score 3):

Your first input has two ID's, which is invalid, and you're passing a date object to the Date constructor.

This is quite simple with plain javascript

```js
$('#term').change(function() {
  var ll = $(this).val();
  var bb = $('#date').val();
  var date = new Date(bb);

  date.setDate(date.getDate() + (+ll));

  var dd = date.getDate();
  var mm = date.getMonth() + 1;
  var y = date.getFullYear();
  var someFormattedDate = dd + '-' + mm + '-' + y;

  $('#due_date').val(someFormattedDate);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="form-group">
  <label for="date">Date:</label>
  <input type="text" id="date" class="form-control" name="date" value="05-05-2017" style="width: 150px;">
</div>
<div class="form-group">
  <label for="term">Term:</label>
  <input type="text" class="form-control" id="term" name="term" value="" placeholder="type here" style="width: 50px;">
</div>
<div class="form-group">
  <label for="due_date">Due Date:</label>
  <input type="text" class="form-control" id="due_date" name="due_date" value="" style="width: 150px;">
</div>
```

Comment: why do i get `16-5-2017` for `Date: 05-05-2017, Term: 10`?

Comment: Because 5 + 11 equals 16. I don't know what `term` is, I just copied the OP's hard coded `11`

Comment: OP uses `term` to add the `date`. that is: `date.getDate() + term`

Comment: You're right, I just deleted it and typed `11`, bad eyesight I guess. Changed it now

Comment: Adebeo, Deleted where in jquery or html

Comment: @LoyBearna - I just edited my answer by deleting a hardcoded value of `11`, as in *eleven*, as I just misread your `ll` variable as such, that's all !

Answer (score -1):

Nan (Not a number) getDate function does not return integer. Object + 11 is not a valid operation (most of the time!).

You can use [Datejs](http://www.datejs.com/) mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19025330/get-tomorrows-date-with-jquery-and-compare)

```
var duedate = new Date.today().addDays(11);
```

Comment: or moment as @Jeremy adviced.