# Get next Date using Selenium IDE / javascript

Tags: javascript, selenium-ide

I can get the current date if I use this...

```
command: storeEval
Target: var d=new Date(); ('0' + (d.getMonth()+1)).slice(-2)+'/'+('0' + d.getDate()).slice(-2) + '/' +d.getFullYear()
Value: testdate
```

Actual Result > 05/14/2015

BUT I need the next date and it is not appearing the format that I wanted.  Let say today's date is 05/14/2015, so I need an output of 05/15/2015. This is what I have as failing

```
command: storeEval
Target: var d=new Date(); ('0' + (d.getMonth()+1)).slice(-2)+'/'+(d.setDate(d.getDate() + 1)) + '/' +d.getFullYear()
Value: testdate
```

Actual Result > 05/1431642394763/2015
Expected Result > 05/15/2015

*Also above I didn't mention about the slice, I need that to work as well if the days go to 1-9.

Please help I need this step in Selenium IDE, any suggestions.

Comment: The return value from [*setDate*](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.9.5.36) is the new time value, not the Date object the method was called on, so you can't chain it like that. You'd need to so something like `(new Date(d.setDate(d.getDate() + 1)).getDate())` but that looks hideous.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Add days to DateTime](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/563406/add-days-to-datetime)

Comment: @AnotherDev—I think the OP is cool with adding the day, just didn't realise what the return value from the *setDate* method was.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9444745/javascript-how-to-get-tomorrows-date-in-format-dd-mm-yy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

found the answer at
[JavaScript how to get tomorrows date in format dd-mm-yy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9444745/javascript-how-to-get-tomorrows-date-in-format-dd-mm-yy)

```
command: storeEval
Target: var d= new Date(new Date().getTime() + (86400000 *2)); ('0' + (d.getMonth()+1)).slice(-2)+'/'+('0' + d.getDate()).slice(-2) + '/' +d.getFullYear()
Value: testdate
```

Expected and Actual Result > 05/16/2015