# Can we check the current time in protractor

Tags: jasmine, protractor

I have one scenario in which I have to book appointment. The limitation is that I can't book appointment in past. I have to automate this scenario.

Is this possible to check the current time and set book appointment time "currenttime +1" in protractor?

Answer (score 3):

Sure, this is still JavaScript, you can [get the tomorrow's date](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9444785/771848) via `Date()`:

```
var date = new Date(new Date().getTime() + 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000);
var day = date.getDate();
var month = date.getMonth() + 1;
var year = date.getFullYear();

var tomorrowDate = day + "/" + month + "/" + year;
```

Then, for example, you can send this `tomorrowDate` string into the appropriate input:

```
element(by.id("appointmentDate")).sendKeys(tomorrowDate);
```

Comment: Assuming by currenttime +1 you meant tomorrow :)

Answer (score 1):

There is a way to set the current date in your date picker.

```
var pickerDue = element(by.model("model of your date picker"));

var today = new Date();
var dd = today.getDate();
var mm = today.getMonth()+1; //January is 0!
var yyyy = today.getFullYear();

if(dd<10) {
   dd='0'+dd
} 

if(mm<10) {
   mm='0'+mm
} 

today = yyyy+'-'+mm+'-'+dd;

pickerDue.clear();
pickerDue.sendKeys(today);
```

This code works for me. If you have a problem, do not hesitate to ask.

Hope this helps. :)