# new Date('2016-10-31') returning Sun Oct 30 2016

Tags: javascript, date, datetime, time, timezone

I'm in the Azores islands and yesterday (30 October 2016) the timezone has changed from GMT+0000 (AZOST) to GMT-0100 (AZOT).

Now `new Date('2016-10-31')` is returning `Sun Oct 30 2016 23:00:00 GMT-0100 (AZOT)`:

[image]

Is this the correct behaviour from the JavaScript Date object? I was expecting the output to be `Mon Oct 31 2016...`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From [this documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) (emphasis mine):

> Note: parsing of date strings with the Date constructor (and
>   Date.parse, they are equivalent) is **strongly discouraged** due to
>   browser differences and inconsistencies. Support for RFC 2822 format
>   strings is by convention only. **Support for ISO 8601 formats differs in
>   that date-only strings (e.g. "1970-01-01") are treated as UTC, not
>   local.**

Comment: And you probably did not notice the difference if you lived in `GMT+0000` until yesterday.