# How to get tomorrow's date of a specific date

Tags: javascript

I am trying to get tomorrow's date of a specific date using JavaScript in format (`yyyy-mm-dd`). For example the specific date is `2021-08-31` and I have got this script:

```
var date  = "2021-08-31"
date = new Date(date.split("-")[0],date.split("-")[1],date.split("-")[2]) 
date.setDate(date.getDate() + 1);
var tomorrows_date_month = date.getMonth()
var tomorrows_date_day = date.getDate()
var tomorrows_date_year = date.getFullYear()
console.log(tomorrows_date_year + "-" + tomorrows_date_month + "-" + tomorrows_date_day)
```

The expected output is:

```
2021-09-01
```

But the output of this code is  :

```
2021-9-2
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9444745/javascript-how-to-get-tomorrows-date-in-format-dd-mm-yy/9444776

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Internally js month is stored as a value between 0 and 11. So you need to minus`date.split("-")[1]` by 1. Otherwise, javascript will think that your month is actually September and we know that "2021-09-32" is translated to "2021-10-2", therefore the date is shown as "2".

```
var date  = "2021-08-31"
date = new Date(date.split("-")[0],date.split("-")[1] - 1,date.split("-")[2]) 
date.setDate(date.getDate() + 1)
var tomorrows_date_month = date.getMonth() + 1
var tomorrows_date_day = date.getDate()
var tomorrows_date_year = date.getFullYear()
console.log(tomorrows_date_year + "-" + tomorrows_date_month + "-" + tomorrows_date_day)
```

Also note that `date = new Date("2021-08-31")` is enough for converting a string into a `Date` object.

Answer (score 2):

First you don't need split `"2021-08-31"` to use as `date` parameter, so just use `new Date("2021-08-31");`

Second note that you need to use `d.getMonth() + 1` and add leading zero if the length is less than `2`:

Try this one:

```js
function formatDate(date) {
    var d = new Date(date),
        month = '' + (d.getMonth() + 1),
        day = '' + d.getDate(),
        year = d.getFullYear();

    if (month.length < 2) 
        month = '0' + month;
    if (day.length < 2) 
        day = '0' + day;

    return [year, month, day].join('-');
}

Date.prototype.addDays = function(days) {
    var date = new Date(this.valueOf());
    date.setDate(date.getDate() + days);
    return date;
}

var date  = "2021-08-31"

var date1 = new Date(date);

console.log(formatDate(date1.addDays(1)));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
new Date(new Date(date + 'T00:00Z').getTime() + 86400000).toISOString().substr(0, 10)
```

The added `'T00:00Z'` assures the date is parsed as UTC, to match the UTC timezone used by `toISOString()`. Adding 86400000 (the number of milliseconds in one day) advances the date without having to fuss with the date field directly.