# How to get the default languge from the ICU library by Country Code

Tags: php, localization, icu

`en_US` gives me `en` for English but it's already in the code

I need `US` to return `en` for English or 'DE' to return `de` for German

```
echo Locale::getPrimaryLanguage('en_US');
echo Locale::getPrimaryLanguage('US');
```

Both of the above should output `en`, but the latter actually outputs `us`.

Comment: You can use the Unicode CLDR [likely subtags data](http://cldr.unicode.org/index/cldr-spec/language-tag-equivalences#TOC-Likely-subtags) to get the “default” or “likely” language for a specific country, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/58512299/1031606

Answer (score 1):

`getPrimaryLanguage` is not an ICU function so I have no idea how it's implemented. In ICU you could call `uloc_addLikelySubtags` which would expand  `und_US` (You would put `und` for unknown before the region code `US`) to `en_US` or `und_DE`  to `de_DE` - and then, calling `uloc_getLanguage` would return `en`, `de`, etc.

Your result of `us` for `US` is probably due to `US` being interpreted as a language code.  You could try `und_US` to see what the behavior is.

Answer (score 0):

like @Steven R. Loomis said you can use a locale 'und_US' and `Locale::getPrimaryLanguage('und_US')` will just return 'und'

If using the php intl extension, it can accept a locale of 'und_US' , but it will no format your currencies properly according to the region US only, you need to specify a language.

```
$locales = array('de_DE', 'en_US', 'ja_JP', 'und_US', 'und_JP', 'und_DE', 'und_FR');
$amount = 1234567.891234567890000;
foreach ($locales as $locale) {
        echo Locale::getPrimaryLanguage($locale).'<br />';
        $formatter = new NumberFormatter($locale, NumberFormatter::CURRENCY); 
        echo $formatter->getTextAttribute(NumberFormatter::CURRENCY_CODE); 
        echo '|' . $formatter->getSymbol(NumberFormatter::CURRENCY_SYMBOL);
        echo '|' . $formatter->getSymbol(NumberFormatter::INTL_CURRENCY_SYMBOL);
        echo ' - ' . $formatter->formatCurrency($amount, $formatter->getTextAttribute(NumberFormatter::CURRENCY_CODE));
        echo '<br /><br />';
}
```

returns

> de EUR|€|EUR - 1.234.567,89 €
>
> en USD|$|USD - $1,234,567.89
>
> ja JPY|￥|JPY - ￥1,234,568
>
> und USD|$|USD - $ 1234567.89
>
> und JPY|¥|JPY - ¥ 1234568
>
> und EUR|€|EUR - € 1234567.89
>
> und EUR|€|EUR - € 1234567.89

notice how even though you are given the correct currency symbol for the region, the format of the number is incorrect.