# How to guess the user "culture" in [language code]_[country code] format in PHP

Tags: php, symfony

How can i guess the user "culture" in [language code]_[country_code] format from the current locale in Symfony2.

I want a function which return a string in the following format :[language code]_[country_code] from the current locale.

Here is the function i search :

```
/**
* @param string $locale ex: "en" 
* @param string $countryCode ex: "GB"
*
* @return string ex: "en_GB"
*/
function getCultureFromLocale($locale, $countryCode = '') {

    //... code to find

    return $culture; 
}
```

Ex:

```
$culture = getCultureFromLocale('en') //return 'en_GB' by default;
$culture = getCultureFromLocale('en', 'GB') //return 'en_GB';
$culture = getCultureFromLocale('en', 'US') //return 'en_US';
```

I hope it's clear enough.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @Chausser I've updated the question.

Comment: So if you are passed `en` you want to infer `en_GB`? or if you are given `en_US` you want to get `en_US`?  Why do you need that anyway?

Comment: Concretelly i need this functionality to call some external APIs using user "culture" in the 'Language_Country' format in theirs URIs. But the only user relative data i have to call these URIs is the current user locale ("en", "fr", ...). So i need a function that returns the most appropriate user "culture" from the user locale. For example it doesn't  matter if the function return "en_GB" or "en_US" if the locale is "en".

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution based on this answer: [Is there a simple way to get the language code from a country code in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10175658/is-there-a-simple-way-to-get-the-language-code-from-a-country-code-in-php/10375234#10375234)

Here is my function (which can be optimised):

```
    function locale_get_culture($locale, $country_code = '')
    {
        //Preferred country for some locales if no country setted
        if (!$country_code) {
            if ($locale == 'fr') {
                $country_code = 'FR';
            } elseif ($locale == 'en') {
                $country_code = 'US';
            } elseif ($locale == 'es') {
                $country_code = 'ES';
            } elseif ($locale == 'de') {
                $country_code = 'DE';
            }
        }

        // Cultures list taken from: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3191664/
        $cultures = array(
            'af-ZA',
            'am-ET',
            'ar-AE',
            'ar-BH',
            'ar-DZ',
            'ar-EG',
            'ar-IQ',
            'ar-JO',
            'ar-KW',
            'ar-LB',
            'ar-LY',
            'ar-MA',
            'arn-CL',
            'ar-OM',
            'ar-QA',
            'ar-SA',
            'ar-SY',
            'ar-TN',
            'ar-YE',
            'as-IN',
            'az-Cyrl-AZ',
            'az-Latn-AZ',
            'ba-RU',
            'be-BY',
            'bg-BG',
            'bn-BD',
            'bn-IN',
            'bo-CN',
            'br-FR',
            'bs-Cyrl-BA',
            'bs-Latn-BA',
            'ca-ES',
            'co-FR',
            'cs-CZ',
            'cy-GB',
            'da-DK',
            'de-AT',
            'de-CH',
            'de-DE',
            'de-LI',
            'de-LU',
            'dsb-DE',
            'dv-MV',
            'el-GR',
            'en-029',
            'en-AU',
            'en-BZ',
            'en-CA',
            'en-GB',
            'en-IE',
            'en-IN',
            'en-JM',
            'en-MY',
            'en-NZ',
            'en-PH',
            'en-SG',
            'en-TT',
            'en-US',
            'en-ZA',
            'en-ZW',
            'es-AR',
            'es-BO',
            'es-CL',
            'es-CO',
            'es-CR',
            'es-DO',
            'es-EC',
            'es-ES',
            'es-GT',
            'es-HN',
            'es-MX',
            'es-NI',
            'es-PA',
            'es-PE',
            'es-PR',
            'es-PY',
            'es-SV',
            'es-US',
            'es-UY',
            'es-VE',
            'et-EE',
            'eu-ES',
            'fa-IR',
            'fi-FI',
            'fil-PH',
            'fo-FO',
            'fr-BE',
            'fr-CA',
            'fr-CH',
            'fr-FR',
            'fr-LU',
            'fr-MC',
            'fy-NL',
            'ga-IE',
            'gd-GB',
            'gl-ES',
            'gsw-FR',
            'gu-IN',
            'ha-Latn-NG',
            'he-IL',
            'hi-IN',
            'hr-BA',
            'hr-HR',
            'hsb-DE',
            'hu-HU',
            'hy-AM',
            'id-ID',
            'ig-NG',
            'ii-CN',
            'is-IS',
            'it-CH',
            'it-IT',
            'iu-Cans-CA',
            'iu-Latn-CA',
            'ja-JP',
            'ka-GE',
            'kk-KZ',
            'kl-GL',
            'km-KH',
            'kn-IN',
            'kok-IN',
            'ko-KR',
            'ky-KG',
            'lb-LU',
            'lo-LA',
            'lt-LT',
            'lv-LV',
            'mi-NZ',
            'mk-MK',
            'ml-IN',
            'mn-MN',
            'mn-Mong-CN',
            'moh-CA',
            'mr-IN',
            'ms-BN',
            'ms-MY',
            'mt-MT',
            'nb-NO',
            'ne-NP',
            'nl-BE',
            'nl-NL',
            'nn-NO',
            'nso-ZA',
            'oc-FR',
            'or-IN',
            'pa-IN',
            'pl-PL',
            'prs-AF',
            'ps-AF',
            'pt-BR',
            'pt-PT',
            'qut-GT',
            'quz-BO',
            'quz-EC',
            'quz-PE',
            'rm-CH',
            'ro-RO',
            'ru-RU',
            'rw-RW',
            'sah-RU',
            'sa-IN',
            'se-FI',
            'se-NO',
            'se-SE',
            'si-LK',
            'sk-SK',
            'sl-SI',
            'sma-NO',
            'sma-SE',
            'smj-NO',
            'smj-SE',
            'smn-FI',
            'sms-FI',
            'sq-AL',
            'sr-Cyrl-BA',
            'sr-Cyrl-CS',
            'sr-Cyrl-ME',
            'sr-Cyrl-RS',
            'sr-Latn-BA',
            'sr-Latn-CS',
            'sr-Latn-ME',
            'sr-Latn-RS',
            'sv-FI',
            'sv-SE',
            'sw-KE',
            'syr-SY',
            'ta-IN',
            'te-IN',
            'tg-Cyrl-TJ',
            'th-TH',
            'tk-TM',
            'tn-ZA',
            'tr-TR',
            'tt-RU',
            'tzm-Latn-DZ',
            'ug-CN',
            'uk-UA',
            'ur-PK',
            'uz-Cyrl-UZ',
            'uz-Latn-UZ',
            'vi-VN',
            'wo-SN',
            'xh-ZA',
            'yo-NG',
            'zh-CN',
            'zh-HK',
            'zh-MO',
            'zh-SG',
            'zh-TW',
            'zu-ZA',
        );

        foreach ($cultures as $culture) {
            $locale_region = locale_get_region($culture);
            $locale_language = locale_get_primary_language($culture);
            $locale_array = array(
                'language' => $locale_language,
                'region' => $locale_region
            );

            if ((($country_code && strtoupper($country_code) == $locale_region) || !$country_code)
                && strtolower($locale) == $locale_language
            ) {
                return locale_compose($locale_array);
            }
        }

        return 'en_US';//default if not found
    }
```