# List of locales for the function money_format second parameter

Tags: php

I want list of all the locale. For example for japan its ja_JP. Like this i want all the list for all the reigons.

```
setlocale(LC_MONETARY, 'ja_JP');
```

I am stuck at this for a long time can someone please help. I also need countries with the codes defined.

Waiting for a positive response.

Answer (score -1):

You'll find your answer in here: [List of All Locales and Their Short Codes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3191664/list-of-all-locales-and-their-short-codes)

From there, you can see which ones of them are useful for the implementation you're looking.

I'll suggest that first run a LONG search in this site and Google, then you can ask for help if you didn't found anything.

Hope this helps you.

Kind regards.