# Required to get current nepal year only in php ?? Is there any solution?

Tags: php, locale

I only get the current year i.e 2014 by `<?php echo date('Y');?>`.
But i want a nepal current date 2071.How to get nepal date will u please help me to get nepal current date.Is there any way to get the current nepali year like `<?php echo date('y');?>`.

Comment: If nothing else helps: https://github.com/amant/Nepali-Date-Convert

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use Carbon for this: https://github.com/briannesbitt/Carbon

The formula is: DateToday + 56 years + 8 months + 15 days

To do this in Carbon:

```
<?php

$todaysDateInGregorian = Carbon::now();
$currentDateInNepal = $todaysDateInGregorian->addYears(56)->addMonths(8)->addDays(15);

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

[Setting the locale](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.setlocale.php) in PHP should provide you with the current date/time.
In order to make use of the current locale you need [`strftime()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strftime.php) instead of `date()`:

```
if(setlocale(LC_TIME, "ne") === false) { // or you can try "ne_NP"
  echo "Could not set locale to ne\n";
}
echo strftime("%Y");
```

(I have not tried this example for the Nepalese locale, as I do not have it readily installed on my system)

On that note: you need to have the required locale installed/available. On a *nix system you can use `locale -a` to find all available/installed locales on your system. See [List of All Locales and Their Short Codes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3191664/list-of-all-locales-and-their-short-codes) for more information on (installing) locales.