# How to convert an ISO date to the date format yyyy-mm-dd?

Tags: javascript, date

How can I get a date having the format yyyy-mm-dd from an [ISO 8601](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) date?

My  8601 date is

```
2013-03-10T02:00:00Z
```

How can I get the following?

```
2013-03-10
```

Comment: `date.split("T")[0]` would do

Comment: Beware `date.split("T")[0]`.  The output may vary depending on the time portion of the Date.  Ex: https://stackoverflow.com/a/71773898/101095

Answer (score 167, accepted):

Try this

```
date = new Date('2013-03-10T02:00:00Z');
date.getFullYear()+'-' + (date.getMonth()+1) + '-'+date.getDate();//prints expected format.
```

**Update:-**

As pointed out in comments, I am updating the answer to print leading zeros for date and month if needed.

```js
date = new Date('2013-08-03T02:00:00Z');
year = date.getFullYear();
month = date.getMonth()+1;
dt = date.getDate();

if (dt < 10) {
  dt = '0' + dt;
}
if (month < 10) {
  month = '0' + month;
}

console.log(year+'-' + month + '-'+dt);
```

Comment: Note, I don't think this will print a leading zero for day or month

Comment: Agree with @user3413723 this doesn't answer the question because it removes leading 0 therefore doesn't meet the requirements of YYYY-MM-DD format

Comment: This is longer and more typo-prone compared to the answer by DriveByPoster.  But I'll not give a downvote because it is more language-agnostic.  It just doesn't use the simple tools at our disposal.

Comment: sir can you please tell me how to pass 2013 3 1 this format date in new Date(date)

Comment: Instead of two IFs, you can simply use `dt = dt.padStart(2, '0'));` and `month = month.padStart(2, '0'));`

Comment: @Avatar close, but that won't work. your variables are numbers, so they don't have `padStart` function. You must use `.toString()` first. Either way, yes, I'd also use `padStart` turning it into nice oneliner :) Not like it can't be turned into oneliner while operating on integers.

Comment: @RoboticRenaissance In a lot of normal uses that answer gives the wrong result. In London, for example, with daylight saving: ```d = new Date("25-Aug-2023"); d.toISOString().substr(0,10)``` leads to ```2023-08-24```

Answer (score 251):

Just crop the string:

```
var date = new Date("2013-03-10T02:00:00Z");
date.toISOString().substring(0, 10);
```

Or if you need only date out of string.

```
var strDate = "2013-03-10T02:00:00Z";
strDate.substring(0, 10);
```

Comment: I think this is the easiest and most elegant solution from them all but is here any downfall for this?

Comment: @Aida_Aida The only issue I can think of is that if your code deals with geoloical-scale time at least 8000 years in the future, your code could break because the format will be `YYYYY-MM-DD` in the year 10000. To avoid this you could split on the `T` character instead. (See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Year_10,000_problem)

Comment: This way won't handle timezones correctly since the ISOString is UTC but the Date object is local. You have to take this in consideration.

Comment: @GuillaumeF. an important consideration but it does comply with OP's requirements

Comment: I can't fathom why the string should be parsed to a Date. The *substring* option seems to be the simplest answer.

Comment: I was just looking for a simple answer for my particular problem so its a +1 from me

Comment: Simple and concise!

Comment: The first option does handle time zones since ISO String is in UTC and `new Date` will convert the string to your time zone. To prove it, paste this in the console `utc= new Date("2022-04-01T23:59:00Z")` (or T00:00:01Z, depending on your zone) and, unless you are in UTC, the outcome will be a different day.

Answer (score 105):

You could checkout [date-fns](https://date-fns.org/) or [Day.js](https://github.com/iamkun/dayjs) for nice date manipulation, including formatting as `YYYY-MM-DD`.

Or just extract the first part of your ISO string, it already contains what you want:

```js
"2013-03-10T02:00:00Z".slice(0, 10) // "2013-03-10"
```

```js
"2013-03-10T02:00:00Z".split("T", 1)[0] // "2013-03-10"
```

Answer (score 37):

This is what I do to get date only:

```js
let isoDate = "2013-03-10T02:00:00Z";

alert(isoDate.split("T")[0]);
```

Comment: This is the first answer to actually propose the split() idea as answer answer as far as I can tell and I like that solution for the effort vs reliability vs effectively factor though I use moment() everywhere I can though.

Comment: toISOString uses UTC, which will produce the wrong local date for the period of the local timezone offset from midnight. – RobG

Answer (score 28):

```js
let isoDate = "2013-03-10T02:00:00Z";
var d = new Date(isoDate);
d.toLocaleDateString('en-GB'); // dd/mm/yyyy
d.toLocaleDateString('en-US'); // mm/dd/yyyy
```

Answer (score 22):

[Moment.js](https://momentjs.com/) will handle date formatting for you. Here is how to include it via a JavaScript tag, and then an example of how to use Moment.js to format a date.

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.14.1/moment.min.js"></script>
```

```js
moment("2013-03-10T02:00:00Z").format("YYYY-MM-DD") // "2013-03-10"
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion. Please also try not to crowd your code with explanatory comments, as this reduces the readability of both the code and the explanations!

Comment: `moment` is a pretty huge library to use just for formatting. Rather use [date-fns](https://date-fns.org/v1.28.5/docs/format) which is much smaller in size and gives the same functionality.

Comment: @Hozefa, then answer the OP question with your solution.

Comment: I wish moment had some function like `.toISODateString()`, because it's very frequent case...

Comment: moment is deprecated.
even moment.js recommend to use another time libs as alternative.https://momentjs.com/docs/#/-project-status/

Answer (score 17):

[Moment.js](https://momentjs.com/) is pretty big library to use for a single use case. I recommend using [`date-fns`](https://date-fns.org) instead. It offers basically the most functionality of Moment.js with a much smaller bundle size and many [`formatting options`](https://date-fns.org).

```
import format from 'date-fns/format'
format('2013-03-10T02:00:00Z', 'YYYY-MM-DD'); // 2013-03-10, YYYY-MM-dd for 2.x
```

One thing to note is that, since it's the [ISO 8601](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) time format, the browser generally converts from UTC time to local timezone. Though this is simple use case where you can probably do `'2013-03-10T02:00:00Z'.substring(0, 10);`.

For more complex conversions `date-fns` is the way to go.

Comment: moment.js is no longer maintained https://momentjs.com/docs/#/-project-status/

Comment: Just a small correction on format argument: 'yyyy-MM-dd' according to date-fns

Answer (score 13):

Using `toLocaleDateString` with the Swedish locale returns a date in ISO format.

```
function getISODate(date) {
    //return date.toLocaleDateString('fr-CA');
    return date.toLocaleDateString('sv-SE');
}
getISODate(new Date()); // '2022-03-24'
```

P.S. This used to work with in Canadian 'en-CA' locale, but now at least since Feb 2023 Firefox and Chromium v110+ use the US date format. It still works in Canadian 'fr-CA' locale. Not sure which one is more future-proof.

Answer (score 10):

To all who are using split, slice and other string-based attempts to obtain the date, you might set yourself up for timezone related fails!

An ISO-String has Zulu-Timezone and a date according to this timezone, which means, it might use a date a day prior or later to the actual timezone, which you have to take into account in your transformation chain.

**See this example:**

```
const timeZoneRelatedDate = new Date(2020, 0, 14, 0, 0);

console.log(timeZoneRelatedDate.toLocaleDateString(
    'ja-JP', 
    {
      year: 'numeric',
      month: '2-digit',
      day: '2-digit'
    }
).replace(/\//gi,'-'));

// RESULT: "2020-01-14"

console.log(timeZoneRelatedDate.toISOString());

// RESULT: "2020-01-13T23:00:00.000Z" (for me in UTC+1)

console.log(timeZoneRelatedDate.toISOString().slice(0,10));

// RESULT: "2020-01-13"
```

Comment: Using `toLocaleDateString` with a Canadian locale returns a date in ISO format. e.g. `date.toLocaleDateString('en-ca')`.

Answer (score 8):

Use:

```
new Date().toISOString().substring(0, 10);
```

Answer (score 6):

This will output the date in YYYY-MM-DD format:

```
let date = new Date();
date = date.toISOString().slice(0,10);
```

Comment: I dont know why this is not getting more votes, it worked perfectly, and answered the question with minimal effort

Comment: This solution fails to properly handle timezones and will lead to unexpected output in many cases.

Answer (score 6):

The best way to format is by using toLocaleDateString with options

```
    const options = {year: 'numeric', month: 'numeric', day: 'numeric' };
    const date = new Date('2013-03-10T02:00:00Z').toLocaleDateString('en-EN', options)
```

Check Date section for date options here https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_tolocalestring.asp

Comment: nice solution but mainly for amercian's i'm afraid

us brits get  '3/10/2013'

"new Date('2013-03-10T02:00:00Z').toLocaleDateString('en-EN', {year: 'numeric', month: 'numeric', day: 'numeric' })
=== '3/10/2013'"

Comment: @aqm you can replace `en-EN` with `en-GB`
This [SO link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3191664/list-of-all-locales-and-their-short-codes) has a list of other locales and their short codes

Answer (score 4):

Pass your date in the date object:

```
var d = new Date('2013-03-10T02:00:00Z');
d.toLocaleDateString().replace(/\//g, '-');
```

Comment: toLocaleDateString() will give in "/" format. Not "-" format.

Comment: You can use the above with a replace of "/" with "-". Not the most elegant though if toLocaleDateString ever changes

Comment: The result of *toLocaleDateString* is not consistent for all users, so may well not produce the result required by the OP.

Comment: Using `toLocaleDateString` with a Canadian locale returns a date in ISO format. e.g. `date.toLocaleDateString('en-ca')`.

Answer (score 4):

**WARNING: Most of these answers are wrong.**

That is because `toISOString()` always returns the UTC date, not local date.  So, for example, if your UTC time is `0500` and your timezone is `GMT-0800`, the day returned by `toISOString()` will be the UTC day, which will be one day ahead of the local timezone day.

You need to first convert the date to the local date.

```
const date = new Date();
date.setTime(date.getTime() - date.getTimezoneOffset()*60*1000)
```

Now `date.toISOString()` will always return the proper date according to the local timezone.

But wait, there's more.  If we are also using `toTimeString()` that will now be wrong because time is now local and `toTimeString()` assumes it is UTC and converts it.  So we need to first extract `toTimeString()` as a variable before doing the conversion.

The `Date()` class in javascript is inconsistent because of this and should really be updated to avoid this confusion.  The `toISOString()` and `toTimeString()` methods should both do the same default things with respect to timezone.

Comment: I think it should be `date.getTime() + date.getTimezoneOffset() * 60 *1000` See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getTimezoneOffset#negative_values_and_positive_values

Answer (score 3):

If you have a date object:

```js
let date = new Date()
let result = date.toISOString().split`T`[0]

console.log(result)
```

or

```js
let date = new Date()
let result = date.toISOString().slice(0, 10)

console.log(result)
```

Comment: *toISOString* uses UTC, which will produce the wrong local date for the period of the local timezone offset from midnight.

Answer (score 3):

A better version of answer by [@Hozefa](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46374497/2926641).

If you have `date-fns` installed, you could use [formatISO](https://date-fns.org/v2.12.0/docs/formatISO) function

```
const date = new Date(2019, 0, 2)
import { formatISO } from 'date-fns'
formatISO(date, { representation: 'date' }) // '2019-01-02' string
```

Answer (score 3):

If you have the timezone you can do:

```
const myDate = "2022-10-09T18:30:00.000Z"
const requestTimezone = "Asia/Calcutta";

const newDate = new Date(myDate).toLocaleString("en-CA", {
  dateStyle: "short",
  timeZone: requestTimezone,
});

console.log(newDate)
>> 2022-10-10
```

Another outputs:

```
const myDate = "2022-10-02T21:00:00.000Z"
const requestTimezone = "Asia/Jerusalem";
>> 2022-10-03 

const myDate = "2022-09-28T04:00:00.000Z"
const requestTimezone = "America/New_York";
>> 2022-09-28
```

Answer (score 2):

To extend on [*rk rk*'s solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25159330/convert-an-iso-date-to-the-date-format-yyyy-mm-dd-in-javascript/25159583#25159583): In case you want the format to include the time, you can add the `toTimeString()` to your string, and then strip the GMT part, as follows:

```
var d = new Date('2013-03-10T02:00:00Z');
var fd = d.toLocaleDateString() + ' ' + d.toTimeString().substring(0, d.toTimeString().indexOf("GMT"));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
let dt = new Date('2013-03-10T02:00:00Z');
let dd = dt.getDate();
let mm = dt.getMonth() + 1;
let yyyy = dt.getFullYear();

if (dd<10) {
    dd = '0' + dd;
}
if (mm<10) {
    mm = '0' + mm;
}
return yyyy + '-' + mm + '-' + dd;
```

Answer (score 0):

I used this:

```
HTMLDatetoIsoDate(htmlDate){
  let year = Number(htmlDate.toString().substring(0, 4))
  let month = Number(htmlDate.toString().substring(5, 7))
  let day = Number(htmlDate.toString().substring(8, 10))
  return new Date(year, month - 1, day)
}

isoDateToHtmlDate(isoDate){
  let date = new Date(isoDate);
  let dtString = ''
  let monthString = ''
  if (date.getDate() < 10) {
    dtString = '0' + date.getDate();
  } else {
    dtString = String(date.getDate())
  }
  if (date.getMonth()+1 < 10) {
    monthString = '0' + Number(date.getMonth()+1);
  } else {
    monthString = String(date.getMonth()+1);
  }
  return date.getFullYear()+'-' + monthString + '-'+dtString
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
    var d = new Date("Wed Mar 25 2015 05:30:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)");
    alert(d.toLocaleDateString());
```

Comment: This isn't in ISO format.

Answer (score 0):

Many of these answers give potentially misleading output if one is looking for the day in the current timezone.

**This function will output the day corresponding with the date's timezone offset:**

```
const adjustDateToLocalTimeZoneDayString = (date?: Date) => {
    if (!date) {
        return undefined;
    }
    const dateCopy = new Date(date);
    dateCopy.setTime(dateCopy.getTime() - dateCopy.getTimezoneOffset()*60*1000);
    return dateCopy.toISOString().split('T')[0];
};
```

**Tests:**

```
it('return correct day even if timezone is included', () => {
    // assuming the test is running in EDT timezone
    // 11:34pm eastern time would be the next day in GMT
    let result = adjustDateToLocalTimeZoneDayString(new Date('Wed Apr 06 2022 23:34:17 GMT-0400'));
    // Note: This is probably what a person wants, the date in the current timezone
    expect(result).toEqual('2022-04-06');

    // 11:34pm zulu time should be the same
    result = adjustDateToLocalTimeZoneDayString(new Date('Wed Apr 06 2022 23:34:17 GMT-0000'));
    expect(result).toEqual('2022-04-06');

    result = adjustDateToLocalTimeZoneDayString(undefined);
    expect(result).toBeUndefined();
});
```

**Misleading approach:**

To demonstrate the issue with the other answers' direct `ISOString().split()` approach, note how the output below differs from what one might expect:

```
it('demonstrates how the simple ISOString().split() may be misleading', () => {
    // Note this is the 7th 
    expect(new Date('Wed Apr 06 2022 23:34:17 GMT-0400').toISOString().split('T')[0]).toEqual('2022-04-07');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use a package like [Luxon](https://moment.github.io/luxon/#/?id=luxon). With this you can parse the full ISO date (`fromISO`) and to with it what you want, for example output to a date only ISO (`toISODate`).

```
const isoDate = DateTime.fromISO('2013-03-10T02:00:00Z').toISODate() // 2013-03-10
```

Answer (score -2):

**Simpler way to get Year Or Month**

```
let isoDateTime = "2013-03-10T02:00:00Z";
console.log(isoDateTime.split("T")[0]); //2013-03-10
```

**Using Split Method**

```
console.log(isoDateTime.split("-")[0]); //2013
console.log(isoDateTime.split("-")[1]); //03
```

Answer (score -2):

Here is a short javascript code to convert ISO 8601 timestamp to a readable local date and time.

```
var myDate = new Date('2013-03-10T02:00:00Z').toString();
console.log(myDate);
```

> Outputs: Sun Mar 10 2013 07:45:00 GMT+0545 (Nepal Time)

Comment: This isn't in ISO format.

Answer (score -2):

A shorter version for @Mritunjay's Answer

```
let d = new Date()
 
mysql_date = d.toISOString().slice(0, 10);
mysql_date = d.getFullYear()+'-' +(d.getMonth()<9?'0':'') + (d.getMonth()+1) + '-'+ (d.getDate()<10?'0':'') + d.getDate();
```

Comment: [A code-only answer is not high quality](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/392712/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers). While this code may be useful, you can improve it by saying why it works, how it works, when it should be used, and what its limitations are. Please [edit] your answer to include explanation and link to relevant documentation.

Answer (score -3):

$moment(date).format("YYYY-MM-DD")

Answer (score -7):

Use the below code. It is useful for you.

```
let currentDate = new Date()
currentDate.toISOString()
```