# Format a date string in javascript

Tags: javascript, string, customization

Hello every i have date field of type string with iso format like this:
const date = "2017-06-10T16:08:00: i want somehow to edit the string in the following format like this: 10-06-2017 but i'm struggling in achieving this.
I cut the substring after the "T" character

Comment: use moment js for achieving this

Comment: why dont you check https://stackoverflow.com/a/25159403/4244010

Comment: ... or https://stackoverflow.com/q/1056728/1169519

Comment: Check this - https://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Use [Moment.js](https://momentjs.com/) and the `.format` function.

```
moment('2017-06-10T16:08:00').format('MM/DD/YYYY');
```

Will output

```
06/10/2017
```

Beside the `format` function [Moment.js](https://momentjs.com/) will enrich you will alot more useful functions.

Comment: Don't offer plugins as the ONLY solution especially when OP didn't ask for it.

Answer (score 21):

It can be achieved without moment.js, but I suggest you use it

```
var date = new Date("2017-06-10T16:08:00");

var year = date.getFullYear();
var month = date.getMonth()+1;
var day = date.getDate();

if (day < 10) {
  day = '0' + day;
}
if (month < 10) {
  month = '0' + month;
}

var formattedDate = day + '-' + month + '-' + year
```

Answer (score 5):

If the date string is always in ISO format, you can also use regex to reformat without other library:

```
date.replace(/(\d{4})\-(\d{2})\-(\d{2}).*/, '$3-$2-$1')
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the JavaScript date() built in function to get parts of the date/time you want.
For example to display the time is 10:30:

```
<script>
var date = new Date();
 var min = date.getMinutes();
  var hour = date.getHour();
   document.write(hour+":"+min);
   </script>
```

To get the year, month, date, day of week use

- getFullYear();
- getMonth();
- getDate();
- getDay();

To get the date you posted:

Comment: var month = date.getMonth()+1;
Month starts counting at 0, so January is 0, February is 1...

Answer (score 1):

If you're looking to do this in vanilla javascript, @Ivan Mladenov's answer is great and can be consolidated slightly using [padStart](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/padStart).

```js
const date = new Date()
const year = date.getFullYear()
const month = String(date.getMonth() + 1).padStart(2, '0')
const day = String(date.getDate()).padStart(2, '0')

console.log(`${day}-${month}-${year}`)
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `Date.toJSON()`

```js
function formatDate(userDate) {
  // format from M/D/YYYY to YYYYMMDD
  return (new Date(userDate).toJSON().slice(0,10).split('-').reverse().join('-'));
}

console.log(formatDate("2017-06-10T16:08:00"));
```

Answer (score -1):

I would like to suggest to use moment js find it - http://momentjs.com/docs/

and use it like

```
    moment(date.toString()).format("MM/DD/YYYY")
```