# Convert database date to short date with Javascript

Tags: javascript, string, date, split, format

I have a SQL lookup a date that feeds into a field, but the date format contains time, I need to convert it to short date (mm/dd/yyyy). The MSSQL outputs this format (m/d/yyyy 12:00:00 AM) notice that the time is always '12:00:00 AM'. How do I remove the time?

```
$('#q60').change(function () {
    var date = $('#q60 input').val();   //looking up the field that contains the date fed from SQL.

    date = date.substring(0, date.indexOf(' '));
  });
```

I have tried using split but while it output the correct thing it doesn't actually change the value in the field for some reason. I have also attempted using the .format similar to this post: [Format a date string in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44493088/format-a-date-string-in-javascript) 
But I am stuck!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

with `date = date.substring(0, date.indexOf(' '));` you're just storing splitted value in to `date` variable. to change the value of the input field add `$('#q60 input').val(date)` at the end of your function.

also in JS there's a whole `Date` object, with it you can format your date as you please. you can find more about it [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) and [here](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_dates.asp)