# How do I reformat the date from openweather api using javascript?

Tags: javascript, date, reformat

How do I format the date I receive from openweather api?
I currently get 2020-10-16 00:00:00 and I want 10-16-2020.

The reason I don't use moment is because I want future dates which come automatically with the 5 day forecast in the api.

Comment: `'2020-10-16 00:00:00'.replace(/(\d{4})\-(\d{2})\-(\d{2}).*/, '$2-$3-$1')`, no library or Date object required.

Answer (score 0):

You can use JavaScript's [Date](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) object.

You might save yourself time by searching a bit more before posting a question, the answer is probably already out there.

- [Where can I find documentation on formatting a date in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1056728/where-can-i-find-documentation-on-formatting-a-date-in-javascript)
- [How to format a JavaScript date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3552461/how-to-format-a-javascript-date)
- [Format JavaScript date as yyyy-mm-dd](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23593052/format-javascript-date-as-yyyy-mm-dd)

Comment: While this is a useful comment, it's not an answer. A Date object isn't required, a [*replace* solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44493245/257182) is more efficient, less code and more robust. :-)

Comment: Why is it not an answer?

Answer (score 0):

You could try to:

- Make a new date based on the date that comes from OpenWeather api
- Convert it to a LocaleDateString using the 'en-US' locale. This will make the month appear before the date.
- Then just split the Date String on the '/' and join in on a '-'. This will substitute the '/' with a '-'

```js
const date = new Date("2020-10-16 00:00:00").toLocaleDateString('en-US');
const formatedDate = date.split('/').join('-');

console.log(formatedDate);
```

Comment: `new Date("2020-10-16 00:00:00")` returns an invalid Date in at least one current browser. See [*Why does Date.parse give incorrect results?*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2587345/why-does-date-parse-give-incorrect-results)

Answer (score -1):

You can always use the built in Javascript [Date](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) object.

In your case you'd want to. do something like this -

```
const myDate = new Date('2020-10-16 00:00:00');
const date = myDate.getDate();
const month = myDate.getMonth() + 1;
const year = myDate.getFullYear();
console.log('MM-DD-YYYY', `${month}-${date}-${year}`);
```

If you want something more convinient and don't want to use moment you can also try some other popular date libraries. You can find some here - https://github.com/you-dont-need/You-Dont-Need-Momentjs

Comment: You should avoid the built–in parser, see [*Why does Date.parse give incorrect results?*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2587345/why-does-date-parse-give-incorrect-results) It seems somewhat inefficient to parse the string to a Date just to use functions to get values that are available in the original string when *split* and *replace* can do that more efficiently and reliably without using a Date object.