# Remove time after converting date toISOString

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

how can I remove the time after converting a date to ISO String?

```
var now = new Date();
console.log( now.toISOString() );
```

if the output is

```
2017-10-19T16:00:00.000Z
```

I just want it to be :

```
2017-10-19
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert ISO Date to Date Format yyyy-mm-dd format in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25159330/convert-iso-date-to-date-format-yyyy-mm-dd-format-in-javascript)

Comment: ` now = (new Date()).toISOString(); now = now.split("T")[0];`

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There are actually many ways to do so:

1- Use [Moment JS](https://momentjs.com/) which gives you kind of flexibility in dealing with the issue

2- The simple way to do it in native JS is to use `substring()` function like that:

```
var date = new Date();
console.log(date.toISOString().substring(0,10));
```

The second way would be more effective if all you need is to remove the time part of the string and use the date only.

Answer (score 13):

One simple but robust approach is to split along the date separator:

```
new Date().toISOString().split('T', 1)[0] // => '2019-03-18'
```

If working with an ISO string of unknown origin, using a Regex pattern as the splitter may prove more reliable (ie. Postgres uses a whitespace as the separator).

```
const isoString = '2019-01-01 12:00:00.000000'

isoString.split(/[T ]/i, 1)[0] // => '2019-01-01'
```

Unlike using `substring`, this approach does not make assumptions about the length of the date (which might prove false for years before 1000 and after 9999).

Comment: I agree, the most robust solution is split on `T` character, which is also an assumption, but lets say the 'T' will stay ;)

Answer (score 2):

Here's how it would be done with momentjs

`var currentDate = moment().format('YYYY-MM-DD');`

Check out the Jsfiddle link: https://jsfiddle.net/cgbcc075/

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way is just to use `split`

```js
var now = new Date();
console.log(now.toISOString().split('T')[0]);
```

Answer (score 1):

It's better to use moment in js for date time related functions. Instantly now you can use substring method:

`var a = "2017-10-19T16:00:00.000Z"
a = a.substring(0,10)`

Answer (score 1):

Computationally fastest way (ie: no unnecessary allocations) would be slicing up to index 10, since ISO8601 timestamp strings have these elements guaranteed, at least for the years 0000 to 9999.

```
let currentDate = new Date().toISOString().substring(0,10);
```