# Display shorter date format

Tags: reactjs

The date is sent from backend in this format:

> "2022-01-01T00:00:00.00000"

How to display date without hours/minutes/seconds like this:

> 2022-01-01?

On my .tsx component I have InputDatepicker:

```
            <InputDatepicker
              label="Training date"
              value={trainingData?.trainingDate || ''}
            />
```

Comment: use momentjs https://momentjs.com to make life easier with DateTime.

Comment: @mehedi Even the Moment project itself [recommends using something newer](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/-project-status/), I would definitely avoid adding it into a new project.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Remove time after converting date toISOString](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47066555/remove-time-after-converting-date-toisostring)

Comment: @DBS thanks . I didn't knew that as I worked with momentjs few years back.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get the first element of the result of split, like this:

```js
console.log("2022-01-01T00:00:00.00000".split('T')[0]);
```

Comment: it looks good, but one more thing - how to use it inside value={ tag?

Comment: @TheFastestTurtle I would first try `(trainingData?.trainingDate || '').split('T')[0]` and see whether that works.

Answer (score 1):

Simple

```
new Date('2022-01-01T00:00:00.00000').toLocaleDateString('en-CA');
```

Answer (score 0):

const newDate = date.slice(0, 10);

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).