# I have Matarial UI datepicker in react and I'm getting 2019-12-08T04:23:53.949Z, I want to remove the T04:23:53.949Z?

Tags: reactjs

```
state = {trip: date: ""}; 

changevalueDate = e => {
 let trip = this.state.trip; 
 trip.date = e.target.value; 
 this.setState({ trip });
};

<TextField label="Start Date" name="Date" 
 InputLabelProps={{ shrink: true, required: true }} 
 type="date" onChange={e => this.changevalueDate(e)}
/>
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is the solution:

```
const date = new Date("2019-12-08T04:23:53.949Z");
//in your case: new Date(state.date)

const mm = date.getMonth() + 1;
const dd = date.getDate();
const yy = date.getFullYear();

const newDate = yy + "-" + mm + "-" + dd;
console.log(newDate);
```

method 2:

```
const date2 = "2019-12-08T04:23:53.949Z"
const newDate2 = date2.substring(0, date2.indexOf("T"));
console.log({ newDate2 });
```

Answer (score 1):

if you want to use `moment`. install that

-step 1

```
npm i moment
```

-step 2

```
const str = '2019-12-08T04:23:53.949Z'
console.log(moment(str).format('MM/DD/YYYY'))
```

Answer (score 1):

*Duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25159330/convert-an-iso-date-to-the-date-format-yyyy-mm-dd-in-javascript)*

Your initial string is an ISO 8601 date.
If all you care about is the `YYYY-MM-DD` part, you can simply take the 10 first strings of your date:

```js
const dateStr = '2019-12-08T04:23:53.949Z'
const newDate = dateStr.substring(0,10)
```