# Save dates to local storage

Tags: javascript, local-storage

Im building a calendar with a synced todo list. I am trying to save a specific date based on the user input to local storage. At the moment the todo is saved to local storage and is presented in a todo list with text and in the calendar but if I refresh the page the todo in the calendar vanishes.

In local storage it's written value:[object HTMLInputElement]

```
function saveTodosToLS() {
 const todosAsString = JSON.stringify(todos);
 localStorage.setItem("todos", todosAsString);
}

function loadTodos() {
 const todosAsString = localStorage.getItem('todos');
 todos = JSON.parse(todosAsString || '[]');
}
```

This is the part Im struggling with

```
function saveCalendarToLS() {
  const todoDateAsString = Date.parse('dateOfTodos');
  todoDateAsString = JSON.stringify(dateOfTodos);
  localStorage.setItem('dateOfTodos', todoDateAsString);
}

function loadTodosInLS() {
  const todoDateAsString = localStorage.getItem('dateOfTodos');
  dateOfTodos = Date.parse(todoDateAsString || '[]');
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by `Date.parse('dateOfTodos')`

Comment: @MirandaNilhag JSON **can** stringify numbers. In my experience the most reliable way to serialize JavaScript `Date` objects to JSON is by saving only the `Date`'s inner Unix timestamp (from `getTime()`) and then rehydrate using the `Date(number)` constructor.

Comment: You cannot pass a DOM element object (like a `HTMLInputElement`) into `localStorage`. You can only pass "POJO" objects (Plain Ol' JavaScript Objects).

Comment: I think you should update that part as so JSON.stringify(todoDateAsString);

Comment: An often useful thing to do while programming is to look at intermediate results when something goes wrong. In this case running `Date.parse('dateOfTodos');` in the browser console, and looking at the values of the local storage values after running the code from the question will likely be informative.

Comment: @Ryan1729 I get NaN when I do that

Comment: @Dai Can you give me an example?

Comment: @SaeedShamloo I use Date.parse because I read that JSON cannot stringify a number and to do so Date.parse should be used. I have only been writing js for a month so it's not easy for me to understand.

Comment: @MirandaNilhag See my posted answer below.

Answer (score 0):

- You should not be using use globals (or any kind of shared-state, really) for passing data around. Programs are *much* easier to understand when data is passed in through function parameters and returned through return-values.
- **Practice *defensive programming***. It's downright *essential* in JavaScript because you don't have the benefit of a compiler to enforce type-safety.

  - What this means in practice is *actually verifying* that function parameter arguments are of the correct type (e.g. `string`, `object`, `Date`, etc) and their values are in expected ranges (e.g. disallow a `Date` value from 1000 years into the future).
- Your `Date.parse` calls are completely incorrect (why are you passing a non-Date string literal?)

I would do it like this:

(Please see my bullet-list of notes below the code)

```
const LOCALSTORAGE_KEY_TODOS = "todos";

function saveTodos( todosArray ) {
    if( !Array.isArray( todosArray ) ) throw new Error( "Expected 'todosArray' to be an array but encountered " + ( typeof todosArray ) ); // Defensive programing!

    const todosAsJson = JSON.stringify( todosArray );

    window.localStorage.setItem( LOCALSTORAGE_KEY_TODOS, todosAsJson );
}

/** Returns an array of todo objects. Returns an empty array if nothing is saved in the store. */
function loadTodos() {
    
    const todosAsJson = window.localStorage.getItem( LOCALSTORAGE_KEY_TODOS );
    if( todosAsJson ) {
        try {
            const todos = JSON.parse( todosAsJson );
            if( Array.isArray( todos ) ) return todos;
        }
        catch( err ) {
            console.error( "Couldn't load TODOs: %o", err );
        }
    }

    return [];
}

function saveCalendar( date, todos ) {
    if( !isDate( date ) ) throw new Error( "Expected 'date' to be a Date object." );
    if( !Array.isArray( todosArray ) ) throw new Error( "Expected 'todosArray' to be an array but encountered " + ( typeof todosArray ) );
    
    const dateKey = 'CALENDAR_' + getDateOnlyString( date );

    const todosAsJson = JSON.stringify( todosArray );
    window.localStorage.setItem( dateKey, todosAsJson );
}

/** Returns an array of todo objects. Returns an empty array if nothing is saved in the store for that date. The time component of 'date' is ignored. */
function loadCalendar( date ) {

    if( !isDate( date ) ) throw new Error( "Expected 'date' to be a Date object." );

    const dateKey = 'CALENDAR_' + getDateOnlyString( date );

    //

    const todosAsJson = window.localStorage.getItem( dateKey );
    if( todosAsJson ) {
        try {
            const todos = JSON.parse( todosAsJson );
            if( Array.isArray( todos ) ) return todos;
        }
        catch( err ) {
            console.error( "Couldn't load TODOs: %o", err );
        }
    }

    return [];
}

/** Returns boolean true or false */
function isDate( value ) {
    // https://stackoverflow.com/questions/643782/how-to-check-whether-an-object-is-a-date

    return value instanceof Date && ( typeof value.getMonth === 'function' );
}

/** Returns `date` formatted as ISO 8601 yyyy-MM-dd */
function getDateOnlyString( date ) {
    // HACK: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25159330/how-to-convert-an-iso-date-to-the-date-format-yyyy-mm-dd
    return date.toISOString().substring(0,10); // "if it works..."
}
```

- Avoid inventing your own acronyms: I see you're using "`LS`" a shorthand for `localStorage`, however that is not a commonplace abbreviation in the JavaScript community, so I would avoid it and just call it what it is: `localStorage`.
- You haven't posted a definition or specification of what a TODO `object` looks like, so my code below does not validate nor verify anything about the TODO objects except that they're actually `object` values.
- Avoid *magic literals*, be they strings or numbers. When you need consistent key strings for collections (as with `window.localStorage`) you should use named constants (e.g. `const LOCALSTORAGE_KEY_TODOS = 'todos';`).
- Remember that a `Date` object in JavaScript actually represents a date **and a time-of-day** value, so you cannot just use any old `Date` object to represent *just* a date. If you use a `Date` *or* its Unix timestamp value (from `Date.getTime()`) you'll find it impossible to retrieve existing items from `localStorage` because their keys will change every millisecond instead of once-per-day.

  - My code below works-around that by using `toISOString()` to get a *full* ISO 8601 date+time string (of the form `yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:sszzz`)  [and uses `.substring(0,10)` as a cheap-trick](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25159330/how-to-convert-an-iso-date-to-the-date-format-yyyy-mm-dd) to trim-off the time-of-day components so that  the returned string only contains date information (this is in `function getDateOnlyString`).
- There is a fair bit of repetitiveness in my code below (e.g. the `loadTodos` and `loadCalendar` functions are almost identical, spare for the `localStorage` key value they use, so that could be rewritten without the duplication of logic. That's an exercise left up for the reader.

Comment: Thanks Dai! I tried it but got this "Uncaught ReferenceError: KEY_TODOS is not defined".

Comment: @MirandaNilhag That was a typo. I've fixed it now, but I had hoped you would have been able to solve that yourself.