# How to get from the date only the date without the time

Tags: javascript

I want to get date without time.

example:
I get the date as: 2022-01-22T00:00:00

How can I remove the: T00:00:00

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substring

Comment: `'2022-01-22T00:00:00'.split('T')[0] ` - or lot more ideas -> [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35393125/13658816)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
let var1 = '2022-01-22T00:00:00'

let output = var1.split('T')[0]
    console.log(output)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
String(new Date('2022-01-22T00:00:00')).split(' ').slice(0, 4).join(' ');
// 'Sat Jan 22 2022'
```