# How to convert Date and time to Javascript ISO Date?

Tags: javascript

I have this form

```
formData = {
    "startDate": "17/04/2022 01:00 AM",
    ....,
}
```

what ive tried so far is

```
var newDate = new Date(formData)
```

ive got Invalid date

resource: https://www.w3schools.com/js/tryit.asp?filename=tryjs_date_string_iso5

Comment: May be useful for you, check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25159330/how-to-convert-an-iso-date-to-the-date-format-yyyy-mm-dd

Comment: You've to modify the string to match a correct date format. A simple way would be this: `const [d, M, y, h, m] = formData.startDate.split(/\/| |:/), date = new Date(y, M, d, h, m).toISOString();`.

Comment: what i want result is like this `Thu Mar 26 2015 02:00:00 GMT+0800 (Philippine Standard Time)`

Comment: That's not an ISO Date. You can get a local date by dropping `.toISOString()` part from my example. There's a small mistake in the code above, the month in the date constructor should be `M - 1`.