# Express/MongoDB date formatting to match req.params to date in mongo document

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, date, restful-url

I have a MongoDB collection (SlopeDay) that has dates stored.

[image]

In my express routing, I'm looking to format the date to MM-DD-YYYY so that I can use that for the URL. That URL will find all documents with matching dates AND matching `resortNames`.

```
dateRouter.get("/:formattedDate", (req, res) => {
  const formattedDate = req.params.formattedDate;

  SlopeDay.find({}) // isolate dates
    .then((dateObj) => {
      dateObj.forEach((date, i) => {
        let dateStr =
          // MM-DD-YYYY reformatting to string
          ("0" + (date.date.getMonth() + 1)).slice(-2) +
          "-" +
          ("0" + date.date.getDate()).slice(-2) +
          "-" +
          date.date.getFullYear();
         // map below doesn't seem to be doing much
        const objWithFormattedDate = dateObj.map((obj) => {
          return { ...obj, formattedDate: dateStr, isNew: true };
        });
        // console.log(objWithFormattedDate);
      });
    });
});
```

I'm at a loss for how to do this properly. I need the get route to access all SlopeDay documents matching dates to the MM-DD-YYYY parameter URL.

Comment: Are the dates in all of your objects stored with no time data? If so, with a little bit of date reformatting, you can pass the param into the `.find()` query without having to do the forEach/map stuff.

Comment: Eventually I'd like them to have no time data. There's no reason to include time in the app. I've made some progress so far with SlopeDay.find({
    date: {
      $gte: new Date("04-13-2022"),
      $lt: new Date("04-15-2022"),
    },

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm able to get it working by breaking the strings up and querying that way:

```
dateRouter.get("/:formattedDate", (req, res) => {
  const formattedDate = req.params.formattedDate;

  // break up the date
  const targetChars = formattedDate.substring(3, 5);
  const beforeTargetChar = formattedDate.substring(0, 3);
  const afterTargetChar = formattedDate.substring(5);

  // create lower and upper boundaries that straddle the formatted date
  const lowerbound = beforeTargetChar + (targetChars - 1) + afterTargetChar;
  const upperbound =
    beforeTargetChar + (Number(targetChars) + 1) + afterTargetChar;

  SlopeDay.find({
    date: {
      // find docs with dates between the boundaries (THIS SHOULD EQUAL req.params.formattedDate)
      $gte: new Date(lowerbound),
      $lt: new Date(upperbound),
    }, // add 2nd query here
  }).then((dateData) => res.send(dateData));
});
```

Comment: Glad you found a solution :) What you did is fine, but you can make things easier for yourself by splitting the formattedDate by the hyphen so you don't have to do the substring stuff. `const dateParts = formattedDate.split('-')`, then you have the month in dateParts[0], day in dateParts[1], and year in dateParts[2].

Comment: ha! Brilliant. So obvious too. Sometimes I get so laser focused on forcing something to work I miss the easiest way to do it. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Just using Javascript I can recommend [this post that might help](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25159330/how-to-convert-an-iso-date-to-the-date-format-yyyy-mm-dd)

Otherwise, there are many libraries you could use to do this as well. Personally I like using Day.JS. Their [format function](https://day.js.org/docs/en/display/format) it would look something like this and should fit your needs and more if you wanted to take that route.

`dayjs(yourDateHere).format('MM-DD-YYYY')`

cheers!

Comment: Interesting - I'm relatively new and had no idea about this. I'll check the library out - thanks!