# Storing an array of dates (without times)

Tags: postgresql, date, adonis.js, lucid

I'm trying to store dates (without times) in a PostgreSQL array.

For context, let's say these are dates on which a supermarket will be closed:

```js
['2022-12-24', '2022-12-25', '2022-12-26']
```

The table is called `opening_times` and there is a column called `closed_days` which has a type of `date[]`:

```js
table.specificType('closed_days', 'date[]').defaultTo([]).notNullable()
```

However, when I `UPDATE` this field using `SET closed_days = '{"2022-10-16"}'`, it seems PostgreSQL is converting it into a full ISO date and time string like this: `["2022-10-15T23:00:00.000Z"]`

According to the PostgreSQL docs (section 8.5), the `date` type is [supposed to have a resolution of 1 day](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-datetime.html), but somehow it is still storing the time. Elsewhere in the database, fields of type `date` do indeed have a granularity of 1 day (time is not stored), but in these instances I am not using an array.

--

Additional information

- I am running PostgreSQL 14.2 inside a Docker container (`psql` is also running inside the container)
- The type of the column in Beekeeper Studio shows as `_date`, but you can see the ORM code above that was used to create the field using type `date[]`, so I assume `_date` is just another notation for the same.
- In `psql`, running `\d opening_times` shows that the column has a type of `date[]`.
- The result of `select array['2022-07-28'::date]` is `["2022-07-27T23:00:00.000Z"]` when run in Beekeeper Studio. When the same query is run in `psql` I get `{2022-07-28}`. When I run it in Lucid ORM:

```js
const db = await Database.rawQuery("select array['2022-07-28'::date]")
console.log(db.rows)
```

I get this: `[ { array: [ 2022-07-27T23:00:00.000Z ] } ]`.

Comment: `select array['2022-07-28'::date];  {07/28/2022}`. What client are you using? What is the `closed_days` type in the database(my bet is timestamp(tz)[])? Add answers as update to question.

Comment: @AdrianKlaver Thanks for your comment.  I'm using Beekeeper Studio but it also seems to happen using Lucid ORM. The type in Beekeeper Studio shows as `_date`, but you can see the ORM code above that was used to create the field using type `date[]`, so I assume `_date` is just another notation for the same. Could you explain the purpose of the `SELECT` query? I'll update the question.

Comment: What is the data type as shown in the database itself? In `psql` do `\d <table_name>` to find it.  The select shows that an array of dates will be `date[]` or it's alias `_date` vs `select array['2022-07-28'::date]::timestamptz[]; {"07/28/2022 00:00:00 PDT"}` which I believe is what is happening. The `date[]` is updating a `timestamptz[]`.

Comment: @AdrianKlaver Oh you must have one of these weird locales, not the default `ISO` datestyle :-) https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=fcf1b2baa6499f1459db970493713cda

Comment: @AdrianKlaver In `psql` the type shows as `date[]`. I ran the `SELECT` query and the result was `["2022-07-27T23:00:00.000Z"]`.

Comment: Add the information in your comments to the question so folks don't have to walk through the comments to get relevant information.

Comment: @Obvious_Grapefruit Where did you run the query, also in `psql`? Or is that the result from your ORM?

Comment: @Bergi, doesn't really change the examples: `set datestyle= 'ISO,MDY' ; select array['2022-07-28'::date]; {2022-07-28}`.

Comment: @Bergi, I initially ran the query in Beekeeper Studio which gave an output of `["2022-07-27T23:00:00.000Z"]`. I just ran it again in `psql` and the result was different - `{2022-07-28}`. I'm running PostgreSQL (and `psql`) in a Docker container if that changes anything. @AdrianKlaver I've updated the question, thanks for reminding me.

Comment: @Obvious_Grapefruit Then apparently Beekeeper Studio is the fault, it does convert `date` values into its own representation. Looks a bit like a JavaScript `Date` in an array that is serialised to JSON. Not a problem with Postgres. Do you actually have code (using your ORM) that is failing, or were you only confused by the Beekeeper Studio output?

Comment: @Bergi It happens in the ORM too, I updated the question with the output.

Comment: So this is JavaScript? And it's using the [node-postgres](https://node-postgres.com/) driver? Then the case is clear: that is converting the `date` string you're getting into a [`Date` object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date). Use [`.toISOString().slice(0, 10)`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25159330/1048572) to get back a date string, or [disable the data type parsing](https://node-postgres.com/features/types).

Answer (score -1):

use moment library

example :

```
moment(new Date()).format("YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss")
```

Comment: Isn't moment deprecated, and no longer being maintained? ([Source](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/-project-status/).)