# How to get ISO currency code by country code in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, locale, currency, country-codes

In my rails app I want to use `country-code`, `currency-code`, `ISO locale code` to fetch some data from API. How can I get this information dynamically when user visit my site from anywhere?

I have used [geocoder gem](https://github.com/alexreisner/geocoder) so by `request.location` I will get location's information and using this gem I can get `country-code`. Now I am not getting how can I get remaining information such as `currency-code` & `ISO locale code`?? Can anyone please help me or guide me??

I have seen this **[money gem](https://github.com/RubyMoney/money)** but not sure it will provide me all these information.

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I have tried [@Prakash Murthy's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27855143/how-to-get-iso-currency-code-by-country-code-in-rails/27855359#27855359) answer. But there are many issue in this http://www.currency-iso.org/dam/downloads/table_a1.xml   I found there is not proper name of all countries and some country has multiple `currency_code` which made me confused. But finally I found the solution by this single [**countries gem**](https://github.com/hexorx/countries) without creating any  database.

Here is how I achieved the solution:

```
country_name = request.location.data['country_name'] # got country name
c = Country.find_country_by_name(country_name) # got currency details
currency_code = c.currency['code'] # got currency code
```

Sorry to answer my own question but I have posted here so in future if anyone stuck like me for the same issue then his/her time not wasted.

Comment: Answering your own question is the right thing to do when you have the answer and it hasn't been posted.  Thanks.

Comment: I don't recommend using the countries gem for this because it uses the currencies gem which has a lot of missing currency information.
https://github.com/hexorx/currencies/pulls

Answer (score 2):

I found a way that makes it really easy:

Add `countries` gem to Gemfile, then `bundle install`

```rb
def currency_for_country(currency_iso_code)

  ISO3166::Country.new(currency_iso_code).currency_code

end
```

Then:

```
currency_for_country('US')
=> "USD"

currency_for_country('AU')
=> "AUD"
```

This info is based off the [countries gem](https://github.com/hexorx/countries#countries) readme

Comment: `::ISO3166::Country[country_code].currency_code`

Answer (score 0):

`currency-code` & `ISO locale code` are static data which change very rarely - if at all, and are best handled as static information within the system by storing them within the database tables. Might even be a good idea to provide a CRUD interface for managing these data.

One possible source for Currency code : http://www.currency-iso.org/en/home/tables/table-a1.html

[List of All Locales and Their Short Codes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3191664/list-of-all-locales-and-their-short-codes) has details about getting the list of all locale codes.

Comment: While I agree that it changes rarely, I don't think it is a good idea to consider it *"static data"*. If your project is going to live 5+ years, it will be the case that you will get lots of inconsistencies. You need to periodically update the list.

Comment: Thanks. That is indeed a valid point; I had not considered it.