# How to get the locale for a specified currency?

Tags: php, locale, currency, setlocale, money-format

I'm in a trouble about this because I have the currencys with the codes of 3 digits (USD, EUR, COP, etc.).

If you go to use the function setlocale you need to do something like this:

setlocale(LC_MONETARY, 'en_US');

Look that you pass 'en_US' and not 'USD'. How can I know for each currency selected by the user the respective locale for LC_MONETARY in order to be used with setlocale.

In addittion, in my website, the currency is independent of the language, for example, you have the website in Spanish but you can see the money in USD. That will result in a locale like: es_US ???? I believe it doesn't supported.

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using this URL I get all language combinations from unicode.org:
http://www.unicode.org/repos/cldr-tmp/trunk/diff/supplemental/language_territory_information.html

I created a table with that languages and its combinations. After that, I run this code (php):

```
$result = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM language" );
while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    putenv('LC_ALL=' . $row['code'] );  
    setlocale(LC_ALL, $row['code'] );
    $arr = localeconv();
    echo $row['code'] . " - " . $arr['int_curr_symbol'] . "<br/>";
}
```

The code is represented by: (Language-Code)_(Territory-Code), and I get something like this:

```
aa - USD 
aa_DJ - DJF 
aa_ER - ERN 
aa_ET - ETB 
ab - ETB 
ab_GE - ETB 
ab_TR - ETB 
abr - ETB 
abr_G - ETB 
ace - ETB 
ace_I - ETB 
ady - ETB 
ady_R - ETB 
ady_T - ETB 
af - ETB 
af_BW - ETB 
af_NA - ETB 
af_ZA - ZAR 
ak - ZAR 
ak_GH - ZAR 
alt - ZAR 
alt_R - ZAR 
am - ZAR 
am_ET - ETB 
am_IL - ETB 
amo - ETB 
amo_N - ETB 
aoz - ETB 
aoz_I - ETB 
ar - ETB 
ar_AE - AED 
ar_AR - AED 
ar_BH - BHD 
ar_CM - BHD 
ar_CY - BHD 
ar_DJ - BHD 
ar_DZ - DZD 
ar_EG - EGP 
ar_EH - EGP 
ar_ER - EGP 
ar_IL - EGP 
ar_IQ - IQD 
ar_IR - IQD 
ar_JO - JOD 
ar_KE - JOD 
ar_KM - JOD 
ar_KW - KWD 
ar_LB - LBP 
ar_LY - LYD 
ar_MA - MAD 
ar_ML - MAD 
ar_MR - MAD 
ar_NE - MAD 
ar_NG - MAD 
ar_OM - OMR 
ar_PS - OMR 
ar_QA - QAR 
ar_SA - SAR 
ar_SD - SDD 
ar_SS - SDD 
ar_SY - SYP 
ar_TD - SYP 
ar_TJ - SYP 
ar_TN - TND 
ar_TR - TND 
ar_YE - YER 
as - YER 
as_IN - INR 
asa - INR 
asa_T - INR 
ast - INR 
ast_E - INR 
atj - INR 
atj_C - INR 
av - INR 
av_RU - INR 
awa - INR 
awa_I - INR 
awa_N - INR 
ay - INR 
ay_BO - INR 
ay_PE - INR 
az_Ar - INR 
az_AZ - AZM 
az_Cy - AZM 
az_La - AZM 
ba - AZM 
ba_RU - AZM 
bal - AZM 
bal_A - AZM 
bal_I - AZM 
bal_O - AZM 
bal_P - AZM 
ban - AZM 
ban_I - AZM 
bap - AZM 
bap_N - AZM 
bbc - AZM 
bbc_I - AZM 
bci - AZM 
bci_C - AZM 
bcl - AZM 
bcl_P - AZM 
be - AZM 
be_BY - BYR 
be_PL - BYR 
be_UA - BYR 
bem - BYR 
bem_Z - BYR 
bew - BYR 
bew_I - BYR 
bez - BYR 
bez_T - BYR 
bfq - BYR 
bfq_I - BYR 
bft - BYR 
bft_I - BYR 
bft_P - BYR 
bfy - BYR 
bfy_I - BYR 
bfy_N - BYR 
bg - BYR 
bg_BG - BGN 
bg_GR - BGN 
bg_MD - BGN 
bg_RO - BGN 
bg_TR - BGN 
bg_UA - BGN 
bgc - BGN 
bgc_I - BGN 
bgx - BGN 
bgx_T - BGN 
bhb - BGN 
bhb_I - BGN 
bhi - BGN 
bhi_I - BGN 
bhk - BGN 
bhk_P - BGN 
bho - BGN 
bho_I - BGN 
bho_M - BGN 
bho_N - BGN 
bi - BGN 
bi_VU - BGN 
bin - BGN 
bin_N - BGN 
bjj - BGN 
bjj_I - BGN 
bjn - BGN 
bjn_I - BGN 
bjn_M - BGN 
bku - BGN 
bku_P - BGN 
bm - BGN 
bm_ML - BGN 
bmq - BGN 
bmq_M - BGN 
bn - BGN 
bn_BD - BDT 
bn_GB - BDT 
bn_IN - INR 
bn_NP - INR 
bo - INR 
bo_CN - CNY 
bo_IN - INR 
bo_NP - INR 
bqi - INR 
bqi_I - INR 
bqv - INR 
bqv_C - INR 
br - INR 
br_FR - EUR 
bra - EUR 
bra_I - EUR 
brh - EUR 
brh_P - EUR 
brx - EUR 
brx_I - EUR 
bs - EUR 
bs_BA - BAM 
bto - BAM 
bto_P - BAM 
btv - BAM 
btv_I - BAM 
btv_P - BAM 
buc - BAM 
buc_Y - BAM 
bug - BAM 
bug_I - BAM 
bug_M - BAM 
bvb - BAM 
bvb_G - BAM 
bxr - BAM 
bxr_R - BAM 
bya - BAM 
bya_I - BAM 
byn - BAM 
byn_E - BAM 
bze - BAM 
bze_M - BAM 
bzx - BAM 
bzx_M - BAM 
ca - BAM 
ca_AD - EUR 
ca_ES - EUR 
ca_FR - EUR 
ca_IT - EUR 
cch - EUR 
cch_N - EUR 
ccp - EUR 
ccp_B - EUR 
ccp_I - EUR 
ce - EUR 
ce_RU - EUR 
ceb - EUR 
ceb_P - EUR 
cgg - EUR 
cgg_U - EUR 
ch - EUR 
ch_GU - EUR 
ch_MP - EUR 
chk - EUR 
chk_F - EUR 
chm - EUR 
chm_R - EUR 
chp - EUR 
chp_C - EUR 
chr - EUR 
chr_U - EUR 
cja - EUR 
cja_K - EUR 
cjm - EUR 
cjm_V - EUR 
ckb - EUR 
ckb_I - EUR 
co - EUR 
co_FR - EUR 
crj - EUR 
crj_C - EUR 
crk - EUR 
crk_C - EUR 
crl - EUR 
crl_C - EUR 
crm - EUR 
crm_C - EUR 
crs - EUR 
crs_S - EUR 
cs - EUR 
cs_CZ - CZK 
csb - CZK 
csb_P - CZK 
csw - CZK 
csw_C - CZK 
cv - CZK 
cv_RU - RUB 
cwd - RUB 
cwd_C - RUB 
cy - RUB 
cy_AR - RUB 
cy_GB - GBP 
da - GBP 
da_DE - GBP 
da_DK - DKK 
da_GL - DKK 
da_IS - DKK 
daf - DKK 
daf_C - DKK 
dar - DKK 
dar_R - DKK 
dav - DKK 
dav_K - DKK 
dcc - DKK 
dcc_I - DKK 
de - DKK 
de_AT - EUR 
de_BE - EUR 
de_BR - EUR 
de_CA - EUR 
de_CH - CHF 
de_CZ - CHF 
de_DE - EUR 
de_DK - EUR 
de_HU - EUR 
de_IT - EUR 
de_KZ - EUR 
de_LI - EUR 
de_LU - EUR 
de_NA - EUR 
de_PL - EUR 
de_PY - EUR 
de_RO - EUR 
de_SK - EUR 
de_US - EUR 
dgr - EUR 
dgr_C - EUR 
dhd - EUR 
dhd_I - EUR 
diq - EUR 
diq_T - EUR 
dje - EUR 
dje_N - EUR 
doi - EUR 
doi_I - EUR 
dtm - EUR 
dtm_M - EUR 
dv - EUR 
dv_IN - EUR 
dv_MV - MVR 
dyu - MVR 
dyu_B - MVR 
dz - MVR 
dz_BT - BTN 
dz_IN - BTN 
ebu - BTN 
ebu_K - BTN 
ee - BTN 
ee_GH - BTN 
ee_TG - BTN 
efi - BTN 
efi_N - BTN 
el - BTN 
el_AL - BTN 
el_CY - EUR 
el_DE - EUR 
el_EG - EUR 
el_GB - EUR 
el_GR - EUR 
el_IT - EUR 
el_RO - EUR 
el_TR - EUR 
el_UA - EUR 
emk - EUR 
emk_G - EUR 
en - EUR 
en_AC - EUR 
en_AG - XCD 
en_AI - XCD 
en_AS - XCD 
en_AU - AUD 
en_AW - AUD 
en_BB - AUD 
en_BE - AUD 
en_BM - AUD 
en_BN - AUD 
en_BS - AUD 
en_BW - BWP 
en_BZ - BWP 
en_CA - CAD 
en_CC - CAD 
en_CK - CAD 
en_CM - CAD 
en_CN - CAD 
en_CX - CAD 
en_DE - CAD 
en_DG - CAD 
en_DM - CAD 
en_DO - CAD 
en_ES - CAD 
en_ET - CAD 
en_FI - CAD 
en_FJ - CAD 
en_FK - CAD 
en_FM - CAD 
en_FR - CAD 
en_GB - GBP 
en_GD - GBP 
en_GG - GBP 
en_GH - GBP 
en_GI - GBP 
en_GM - GBP 
en_GU - GBP 
en_GY - GBP 
en_HK - HKD 
en_HN - HKD 
en_IE - EUR 
en_IL - EUR 
en_IM - EUR 
en_IN - INR 
en_IO - INR 
en_IT - INR 
en_JE - INR 
en_JM - INR 
en_KE - INR 
en_KI - INR 
en_KN - INR 
en_KY - INR 
en_LB - INR 
en_LC - INR 
en_LK - INR 
en_LR - INR 
en_LS - INR 
en_MG - INR 
en_MH - INR 
en_MP - INR 
en_MS - INR 
en_MT - INR 
en_MU - INR 
en_MW - INR 
en_MY - INR 
en_NA - INR 
en_NF - INR 
en_NG - NGN 
en_NL - NGN 
en_NR - NGN 
en_NU - NGN 
en_NZ - NZD 
en_PA - NZD 
en_PG - NZD 
en_PH - PHP 
en_PI - PHP 
en_PK - PHP 
en_PM - PHP 
en_PN - PHP 
en_PR - PHP 
en_PW - PHP 
en_RW - PHP 
en_SB - PHP 
en_SC - PHP 
en_SG - SGD 
en_SH - SGD 
en_SL - SGD 
en_SS - SGD 
en_SZ - SGD 
en_TA - SGD 
en_TC - SGD 
en_TK - SGD 
en_TO - SGD 
en_TT - SGD 
en_TV - SGD 
en_TZ - SGD 
en_UD - SGD 
en_UG - SGD 
en_UM - SGD 
en_US - USD 
en_VC - USD 
en_VG - USD 
en_VI - USD 
en_VU - USD 
en_WS - USD 
en_ZA - ZAR 
en_ZM - ZAR 
en_ZW - ZWD 
eo - ZWD 
eo_EO - ZWD 
eo_SM - ZWD 
es - ZWD 
es_AD - ZWD 
es_AR - ARS 
es_BO - BOB 
es_BZ - BOB 
es_CL - CLP 
es_CO - COP 
es_CR - CRC 
es_CU - CRC 
es_DE - CRC 
es_DO - DOP 
es_EA - DOP 
es_EC - USD 
es_ES - EUR 
es_GQ - EUR 
es_GT - GTQ 
es_HN - HNL 
es_IC - HNL 
es_LA - HNL 
es_MA - HNL 
es_MX - MXN 
es_NI - NIO 
es_PA - PAB 
es_PE - PEN 
es_PH - PEN 
es_PR - USD 
es_PY - PYG 
es_SV - SVC 
es_TT - SVC 
es_US - USD 
es_UY - UYU 
es_VE - VEB 
et - VEB 
et_EE - EEK 
et_FI - EEK 
eu - EEK 
eu_ES - EUR 
eu_FR - EUR 
fa - EUR 
fa_AE - EUR 
fa_AF - EUR 
fa_IQ - EUR 
fa_IR - IRR 
fa_OM - IRR 
fa_PK - IRR 
fa_QA - IRR 
fa_TJ - IRR 
fan - IRR 
fan_G - IRR 
fb_LT - IRR 
ff - IRR 
ff_GN - IRR 
ff_MR - IRR 
ff_SN - IRR 
ffm - IRR 
ffm_M - IRR 
fi - IRR 
fi_FI - EUR 
fi_RU - EUR 
fi_SE - EUR 
fil - EUR 
fil_P - EUR 
fj - EUR 
fj_FJ - EUR 
fo - EUR 
fo_FO - DKK 
fon - DKK 
fon_B - DKK 
fr - DKK 
fr_AD - DKK 
fr_BE - EUR 
fr_BF - EUR 
fr_BI - EUR 
fr_BJ - EUR 
fr_BL - EUR 
fr_CA - CAD 
fr_CD - CAD 
fr_CF - CAD 
fr_CG - CAD 
fr_CH - CHF 
fr_CI - CHF 
fr_CM - CHF 
fr_CP - CHF 
fr_DJ - CHF 
fr_DZ - CHF 
fr_FR - EUR 
fr_GA - EUR 
fr_GB - EUR 
fr_GF - EUR 
fr_GN - EUR 
fr_GP - EUR 
fr_GQ - EUR 
fr_HT - EUR 
fr_IT - EUR 
fr_KM - EUR 
fr_LB - EUR 
fr_LU - EUR 
fr_MA - EUR 
fr_MC - EUR 
fr_MF - EUR 
fr_MG - EUR 
fr_ML - EUR 
fr_MQ - EUR 
fr_MR - EUR 
fr_MU - EUR 
fr_NC - EUR 
fr_NE - EUR 
fr_PF - EUR 
fr_PM - EUR 
fr_RE - EUR 
fr_RW - EUR 
fr_SC - EUR 
fr_SN - EUR 
fr_SY - EUR 
fr_TD - EUR 
fr_TF - EUR 
fr_TG - EUR 
fr_TN - EUR 
fr_US - EUR 
fr_VU - EUR 
fr_WF - EUR 
fr_YT - EUR 
fud - EUR 
fud_W - EUR 
fuq - EUR 
fuq_N - EUR 
fur - EUR 
fur_I - EUR 
fuv - EUR 
fuv_N - EUR 
fy - EUR 
fy_NL - EUR 
ga - EUR 
ga_GB - EUR 
ga_IE - EUR 
gaa - EUR 
gaa_G - EUR 
gag - EUR 
gag_M - EUR 
gbm - EUR 
gbm_I - EUR 
gcr - EUR 
gcr_G - EUR 
gd - EUR 
gd_GB - GBP 
ggn - GBP 
ggn_N - GBP 
gil - GBP 
gil_K - GBP 
gjk - GBP 
gjk_P - GBP 
gju - GBP 
gju_P - GBP 
gl - GBP 
gl_ES - EUR 
gl_PT - EUR 
glk - EUR 
glk_I - EUR 
gn - EUR 
gn_AR - EUR 
gn_BO - EUR 
gn_PY - EUR 
gno - EUR 
gno_I - EUR 
gon - EUR 
gon_I - EUR 
gor - EUR 
gor_I - EUR 
gos - EUR 
gos_N - EUR 
grt - EUR 
grt_B - EUR 
grt_I - EUR 
gsw - EUR 
gsw_C - EUR 
gsw_F - EUR 
gsw_L - EUR 
gu - EUR 
gu_IN - INR 
gu_KE - INR 
gub - INR 
gub_B - INR 
guz - INR 
guz_K - INR 
gv - INR 
gv_IM - INR 
gvr - INR 
gvr_N - INR 
gwi - INR 
gwi_C - INR 
ha_Ar - INR 
ha_La - INR 
haw - INR 
haw_U - INR 
haz - INR 
haz_A - INR 
he - INR 
he_IL - ILS 
hi - ILS 
hi_FJ - ILS 
hi_IN - INR 
hi_NP - INR 
hi_UG - INR 
hi_ZA - INR 
hil - INR 
hil_P - INR 
hnd - INR 
hnd_P - INR 
hne - INR 
hne_I - INR 
hnn - INR 
hnn_P - INR 
hno - INR 
hno_P - INR 
ho - INR 
ho_PG - INR 
hoc - INR 
hoc_I - INR 
hoj - INR 
hoj_I - INR 
hr - INR 
hr_AT - INR 
hr_BA - INR 
hr_DE - INR 
hr_HR - HRK 
hr_HU - HRK 
hr_IT - HRK 
ht - HRK 
ht_HT - HTG 
hu - HTG 
hu_AT - HTG 
hu_HU - HUF 
hu_IL - HUF 
hu_RO - HUF 
hu_RS - HUF 
hu_SI - HUF 
hu_SK - HUF 
hu_UA - HUF 
hy - HUF 
hy_AM - AMD 
hy_CY - AMD 
hy_GE - AMD 
hy_IR - AMD 
hy_LB - AMD 
hy_SY - AMD 
hy_TR - AMD 
ia - AMD 
ia_SE - AMD 
ibb - AMD 
ibb_N - AMD 
id - AMD 
id_ID - IDR 
id_NL - IDR 
ig - IDR 
ig_NG - NGN 
ii - NGN 
ii_CN - NGN 
ik - NGN 
ik_US - NGN 
ike - NGN 
ike_C - NGN 
ikt - NGN 
ikt_C - NGN 
iku - NGN 
iku_C - NGN 
ilo - NGN 
ilo_P - NGN 
inh - NGN 
inh_R - NGN 
is - NGN 
is_IS - ISK 
it - ISK 
it_AU - ISK 
it_BR - ISK 
it_CA - ISK 
it_CH - CHF 
it_DE - CHF 
it_FR - CHF 
it_GB - CHF 
it_HR - CHF 
it_IT - EUR 
it_SI - EUR 
it_SM - EUR 
it_US - EUR 
it_VA - EUR 
iu - EUR 
iu_GL - EUR 
ja - EUR 
ja_BR - EUR 
ja_JP - JPY 
jmc - JPY 
jmc_T - JPY 
jml - JPY 
jml_N - JPY 
jv - JPY 
jv_ID - JPY 
jv_MY - JPY 
ka - JPY 
ka_GE - GEL 
ka_IR - GEL 
ka_TR - GEL 
kaa - GEL 
kaa_U - GEL 
kab - GEL 
kab_D - GEL 
kaj - GEL 
kaj_N - GEL 
kam - GEL 
kam_K - GEL 
kao - GEL 
kao_M - GEL 
kbd - GEL 
kbd_R - GEL 
kbd_T - GEL 
kcg - GEL 
kcg_N - GEL 
kck - GEL 
kck_Z - GEL 
kde - GEL 
kde_T - GEL 
kdt - GEL 
kdt_K - GEL 
kdt_L - GEL 
kdt_T - GEL 
kea - GEL 
kea_C - GEL 
kfo - GEL 
kfo_C - GEL 
kfr - GEL 
kfr_I - GEL 
kfy - GEL 
kfy_I - GEL 
kg - GEL 
kg_CD - GEL 
kge - GEL 
kge_I - GEL 
kgp - GEL 
kgp_B - GEL 
kha - GEL 
kha_I - GEL 
khb - GEL 
khb_C - GEL 
khn - GEL 
khn_I - GEL 
khq - GEL 
khq_M - GEL 
kht - GEL 
kht_I - GEL 
kht_M - GEL 
khw - GEL 
khw_P - GEL 
ki - GEL 
ki_KE - GEL 
kj - GEL 
kj_NA - GEL 
kk_Ar - GEL 
kk_Cy - GEL 
kl - GEL 
kl_DK - GEL 
kl_GL - DKK 
kln - DKK 
kln_K - DKK 
km - DKK 
km_KH - KHR 
kmb - KHR 
kmb_A - KHR 
kn - KHR 
kn_IN - INR 
ko - INR 
ko_BR - INR 
ko_CN - INR 
ko_JP - INR 
ko_KP - INR 
ko_KR - KRW 
ko_US - KRW 
koi - KRW 
koi_R - KRW 
kok - KRW 
kok_I - KRW 
kos - KRW 
kos_F - KRW 
kpe - KRW 
kpe_G - KRW 
kpe_L - KRW 
kpv - KRW 
kpv_R - KRW 
krc - KRW 
krc_R - KRW 
kri - KRW 
kri_S - KRW 
krl - KRW 
krl_R - KRW 
kru - KRW 
kru_I - KRW 
ks - KRW 
ks_GB - KRW 
ks_IN - INR 
ks_PK - INR 
ksb - INR 
ksb_T - INR 
ksh - INR 
ksh_D - INR 
ku_Ar - INR 
ku_La - INR 
ku_TR - TRY 
kum - TRY 
kum_R - TRY 
kvr - TRY 
kvr_I - TRY 
kvx - TRY 
kvx_P - TRY 
kw - TRY 
kw_GB - GBP 
kxm - GBP 
kxm_T - GBP 
kxp - GBP 
kxp_P - GBP 
ky_Ar - GBP 
ky_Cy - GBP 
ky_La - GBP 
la - GBP 
la_VA - GBP 
lag - GBP 
lag_T - GBP 
lah - GBP 
lah_I - GBP 
lah_P - GBP 
laj - GBP 
laj_U - GBP 
lb - GBP 
lb_LU - GBP 
lbe - GBP 
lbe_R - GBP 
lbw - GBP 
lbw_I - GBP 
lcp - GBP 
lcp_C - GBP 
lcp_T - GBP 
lep - GBP 
lep_B - GBP 
lep_I - GBP 
lep_N - GBP 
lez - GBP 
lez_R - GBP 
lg - GBP 
lg_UG - UGX 
li - UGX 
li_NL - EUR 
lif - EUR 
lif_I - EUR 
lif_N - EUR 
lis - EUR 
lis_C - EUR 
ljp - EUR 
ljp_I - EUR 
lki - EUR 
lki_I - EUR 
lmn - EUR 
lmn_I - EUR 
lmo - EUR 
lmo_C - EUR 
ln - EUR 
ln_CD - EUR 
ln_CG - EUR 
lo - EUR 
lo_LA - LAK 
lol - LAK 
lol_C - LAK 
lrc - LAK 
lrc_I - LAK 
lt - LAK 
lt_LT - LTL 
lu - LTL 
lu_CD - LTL 
lua - LTL 
lua_C - LTL 
luo - LTL 
luo_K - LTL 
luy - LTL 
luy_K - LTL 
luz - LTL 
luz_I - LTL 
lv - LTL 
lv_LV - LVL 
lwl - LVL 
lwl_T - LVL 
mad - LVL 
mad_I - LVL 
mag - LVL 
mag_I - LVL 
mai - LVL 
mai_I - LVL 
mai_N - LVL 
mak - LVL 
mak_I - LVL 
mas - LVL 
mas_K - LVL 
mas_T - LVL 
maz - LVL 
maz_M - LVL 
mdf - LVL 
mdf_R - LVL 
mdh - LVL 
mdh_P - LVL 
mdr - LVL 
mdr_I - LVL 
mdt - LVL 
mdt_G - LVL 
men - LVL 
men_L - LVL 
men_S - LVL 
mer - LVL 
mer_K - LVL 
mfa - LVL 
mfa_T - LVL 
mfe - LVL 
mfe_M - LVL 
mg - LVL 
mg_MG - MGA 
mgp - MGA 
mgp_N - MGA 
mgy - MGA 
mgy_I - MGA 
mh - MGA 
mh_MH - MGA 
mhr - MGA 
mhr_R - MGA 
mi - MGA 
mi_NZ - NZD 
min - NZD 
min_I - NZD 
mk - NZD 
mk_AL - NZD 
mk_GR - NZD 
mk_MK - MKD 
ml - MKD 
ml_AE - MKD 
ml_BH - MKD 
ml_GB - MKD 
ml_IL - MKD 
ml_IN - INR 
ml_MY - INR 
ml_QA - INR 
ml_SG - INR 
mn_Cy - INR 
mn_Mo - INR 
mni - INR 
mni_B - INR 
mni_I - INR 
mnw - INR 
mnw_M - INR 
mnw_T - INR 
moe - INR 
moe_C - INR 
mos - INR 
mos_B - INR 
mr - INR 
mr_IN - INR 
mrd - INR 
mrd_N - INR 
mrj - INR 
mrj_R - INR 
ms - INR 
ms_BN - INR 
ms_CC - INR 
ms_ID - INR 
ms_MY - MYR 
ms_SG - MYR 
mt - MYR 
mt_MT - EUR 
mtr - EUR 
mtr_I - EUR 
mup - EUR 
mup_I - EUR 
mvy - EUR 
mvy_P - EUR 
mwk - EUR 
mwk_M - EUR 
mwr - EUR 
mwr_I - EUR 
mxc - EUR 
mxc_Z - EUR 
my - EUR 
my_BD - EUR 
my_MM - MMK 
myv - MMK 
myv_R - MMK 
myx - MMK 
myx_U - MMK 
na - MMK 
na_NR - MMK 
nap - MMK 
nap_I - MMK 
naq - MMK 
naq_N - MMK 
nb - MMK 
nb_NO - NOK 
nb_SJ - NOK 
nbf - NOK 
nbf_C - NOK 
nch - NOK 
nch_M - NOK 
nd - NOK 
nd_ZW - NOK 
ndc - NOK 
ndc_M - NOK 
ndc_Z - NOK 
nds - NOK 
nds_D - NOK 
ne - NOK 
ne_BT - NOK 
ne_IN - NOK 
ne_NP - INR 
new - INR 
new_N - INR 
ng - INR 
ng_NA - INR 
ngl - INR 
ngl_M - INR 
nhe - INR 
nhe_M - INR 
nhw - INR 
nhw_M - INR 
nij - INR 
nij_I - INR 
niu - INR 
niu_N - INR 
nl - INR 
nl_AW - AWG 
nl_BE - EUR 
nl_DE - EUR 
nl_FR - EUR 
nl_NL - EUR 
nl_SR - EUR 
nn - EUR 
nn_NO - NOK 
nod - NOK 
nod_T - NOK 
noe - NOK 
noe_I - NOK 
nr - NOK 
nr_ZA - ZAR 
nsk - ZAR 
nsk_C - ZAR 
nso - ZAR 
nso_Z - ZAR 
nv - ZAR 
nv_US - ZAR 
ny - ZAR 
ny_MW - ZAR 
ny_MZ - ZAR 
ny_ZM - ZAR 
ny_ZW - ZAR 
nym - ZAR 
nym_T - ZAR 
nyn - ZAR 
nyn_U - ZAR 
oc - ZAR 
oc_FR - EUR 
om - EUR 
om_ET - ETB 
om_KE - KES 
om_SO - KES 
or - KES 
or_IN - INR 
os - INR 
os_GE - INR 
pa_Ar - INR 
pa_Gu - INR 
pa_IN - INR 
pag - INR 
pag_P - INR 
pam - INR 
pam_P - INR 
pap - INR 
pap_A - INR 
pau - INR 
pau_P - INR 
pko - INR 
pko_K - INR 
pl - INR 
pl_CZ - INR 
pl_DE - INR 
pl_IL - INR 
pl_PL - PLN 
pl_RO - PLN 
pl_SK - PLN 
pl_UA - PLN 
pon - PLN 
pon_F - PLN 
prd - PLN 
prd_A - PLN 
prd_I - PLN 
ps - PLN 
ps_AE - PLN 
ps_AF - AFN 
ps_IR - AFN 
ps_PK - AFN 
pt - AFN 
pt_AG - AFN 
pt_AO - AFN 
pt_BR - BRL 
pt_CV - BRL 
pt_FR - BRL 
pt_GW - BRL 
pt_MO - BRL 
pt_MZ - BRL 
pt_PT - EUR 
pt_ST - EUR 
pt_TL - EUR 
puu - EUR 
puu_G - EUR 
qu - EUR 
qu_BO - EUR 
qu_PE - EUR 
rcf - EUR 
rcf_R - EUR 
rej - EUR 
rej_I - EUR 
ria - EUR 
ria_I - EUR 
rif - EUR 
rif_M - EUR 
rif_N - EUR 
rjb - EUR 
rjb_N - EUR 
rm - EUR 
rm_CH - EUR 
rmf - EUR 
rmf_F - EUR 
rmo - EUR 
rmo_C - EUR 
rmt - EUR 
rmt_I - EUR 
rn - EUR 
rn_BI - EUR 
rng - EUR 
rng_M - EUR 
ro - EUR 
ro_HU - EUR 
ro_IL - EUR 
ro_MD - EUR 
ro_RO - RON 
ro_RS - RON 
ro_UA - RON 
rof - RON 
rof_T - RON 
ru - RON 
ru_BY - RON 
ru_CN - RON 
ru_DE - RON 
ru_EE - RON 
ru_FI - RON 
ru_GE - RON 
ru_IL - RON 
ru_KG - RON 
ru_KZ - RON 
ru_LT - RON 
ru_LV - RON 
ru_MD - RON 
ru_MN - RON 
ru_RU - RUB 
ru_SJ - RUB 
ru_TM - RUB 
ru_UA - UAH 
ru_US - UAH 
ru_UZ - UAH 
rue - UAH 
rue_U - UAH 
rw - UAH 
rw_CD - UAH 
rw_RW - RWF 
rw_UG - RWF 
rwk - RWF 
rwk_T - RWF 
ryu - RWF 
ryu_J - RWF 
sa - RWF 
sa_IN - INR 
sah - INR 
sah_R - INR 
saq - INR 
saq_K - INR 
sas - INR 
sas_I - INR 
sat - INR 
sat_I - INR 
saz - INR 
saz_I - INR 
sck - INR 
sck_I - INR 
scn - INR 
scn_I - INR 
sco - INR 
sco_G - INR 
scs - INR 
scs_C - INR 
sd_Ar - INR 
sd_De - INR 
sdh - INR 
sdh_I - INR 
se - INR 
se_FI - INR 
se_NO - NOK 
se_SE - NOK 
sef - NOK 
sef_C - NOK 
seh - NOK 
seh_M - NOK 
ses - NOK 
ses_M - NOK 
sg - NOK 
sg_CF - NOK 
shi_L - NOK 
shi_T - NOK 
shn - NOK 
shn_M - NOK 
shn_T - NOK 
si - NOK 
si_LK - LKR 
sid - LKR 
sid_E - LKR 
sk - LKR 
sk_HU - LKR 
sk_RS - LKR 
sk_SK - EUR 
skr - EUR 
skr_P - EUR 
sl - EUR 
sl_AT - EUR 
sl_HU - EUR 
sl_IT - EUR 
sl_SI - EUR 
sm - EUR 
sm_AS - EUR 
sm_WS - EUR 
sma - EUR 
sma_S - EUR 
smj - EUR 
smj_S - EUR 
smn - EUR 
smn_F - EUR 
sms - EUR 
sms_F - EUR 
sn - EUR 
sn_ZW - EUR 
snk - EUR 
snk_M - EUR 
so - EUR 
so_DJ - DJF 
so_ET - ETB 
so_KE - ETB 
so_SO - SOS 
sou - SOS 
sou_T - SOS 
sq - SOS 
sq_AL - ALL 
sq_GR - ALL 
sq_ME - ALL 
sq_MK - MKD 
sq_RS - MKD 
sq_TR - MKD 
sr_Cy - MKD 
sr_La - MKD 
sr_RS - RSD 
srn - RSD 
srn_S - RSD 
srr - RSD 
srr_S - RSD 
srx - RSD 
srx_I - RSD 
ss - RSD 
ss_LS - RSD 
ss_SZ - RSD 
ss_ZA - ZAR 
ssy - ZAR 
ssy_E - ZAR 
st - ZAR 
st_LS - ZAR 
st_ZA - ZAR 
su - ZAR 
su_ID - ZAR 
suk - ZAR 
suk_T - ZAR 
sus - ZAR 
sus_G - ZAR 
sv - ZAR 
sv_AX - ZAR 
sv_FI - EUR 
sv_SE - SEK 
sw - SEK 
sw_BI - SEK 
sw_CD - SEK 
sw_KE - SEK 
sw_MZ - SEK 
sw_SO - SEK 
sw_TZ - SEK 
sw_UG - SEK 
sw_YT - SEK 
sw_ZA - SEK 
swb - SEK 
swb_Y - SEK 
swv - SEK 
swv_I - SEK 
sxn - SEK 
sxn_I - SEK 
syi - SEK 
syi_G - SEK 
syl - SEK 
syl_B - SEK 
syl_G - SEK 
syr - SEK 
syr_S - SEK 
ta - SEK 
ta_IN - INR 
ta_LK - INR 
ta_MU - INR 
ta_MY - INR 
ta_RE - INR 
ta_SG - INR 
taj - INR 
taj_N - INR 
tbw - INR 
tbw_P - INR 
tcy - INR 
tcy_I - INR 
tdd - INR 
tdd_C - INR 
tdg - INR 
tdg_N - INR 
tdh - INR 
tdh_N - INR 
te - INR 
te_IN - INR 
tem - INR 
tem_S - INR 
teo - INR 
teo_K - INR 
teo_U - INR 
tet - INR 
tet_T - INR 
tg_Ar - INR 
tg_Cy - INR 
th - INR 
th_TH - THB 
thl - THB 
thl_N - THB 
thq - THB 
thq_N - THB 
thr - THB 
thr_N - THB 
ti - THB 
ti_ER - ERN 
ti_ET - ETB 
ti_IL - ETB 
tig - ETB 
tig_E - ETB 
tiv - ETB 
tiv_N - ETB 
tk - ETB 
tk_AF - ETB 
tk_IR - ETB 
tk_TM - TMM 
tkl - TMM 
tkl_T - TMM 
tkt - TMM 
tkt_N - TMM 
tl - TMM 
tl_PH - PHP 
tl_US - PHP 
tmh - PHP 
tmh_M - PHP 
tmh_N - PHP 
tn - PHP 
tn_BW - PHP 
tn_NA - PHP 
tn_ZA - ZAR 
tn_ZW - ZAR 
to - ZAR 
to_TO - ZAR 
tpi - ZAR 
tpi_P - ZAR 
tr - ZAR 
tr_BG - ZAR 
tr_CY - TRY 
tr_DE - TRY 
tr_GR - TRY 
tr_MK - TRY 
tr_NL - TRY 
tr_RO - TRY 
tr_TR - TRY 
tr_UA - TRY 
tr_UZ - TRY 
trv - TRY 
trv_T - TRY 
ts - TRY 
ts_MZ - TRY 
ts_SZ - TRY 
ts_ZA - ZAR 
tsf - ZAR 
tsf_N - ZAR 
tsg - ZAR 
tsg_P - ZAR 
tsj - ZAR 
tsj_B - ZAR 
tt - ZAR 
tt_RU - RUB 
ttj - RUB 
ttj_U - RUB 
tts - RUB 
tts_T - RUB 
tum - RUB 
tum_M - RUB 
tvl - RUB 
tvl_T - RUB 
twq - RUB 
twq_N - RUB 
ty - RUB 
ty_PF - RUB 
tyv - RUB 
tyv_R - RUB 
tzm - RUB 
tzm_M - RUB 
udm - RUB 
udm_R - RUB 
ug_Ar - RUB 
ug_Cy - RUB 
uk - RUB 
uk_PL - RUB 
uk_SK - RUB 
uk_UA - UAH 
uli - UAH 
uli_F - UAH 
umb - UAH 
umb_A - UAH 
unr - UAH 
unr_I - UAH 
unr_N - UAH 
unx - UAH 
unx_I - UAH 
ur - UAH 
ur_IN - UAH 
ur_MU - UAH 
ur_PK - PKR 
uz_Ar - PKR 
uz_Cy - PKR 
uz_La - PKR 
vai - PKR 
vai_L - PKR 
ve - PKR 
ve_ZA - ZAR 
ve_ZW - ZAR 
vi - ZAR 
vi_CN - ZAR 
vi_US - ZAR 
vi_VN - VND 
vmw - VND 
vmw_M - VND 
vun - VND 
vun_T - VND 
wa - VND 
wa_BE - EUR 
wae - EUR 
wae_C - EUR 
wae_L - EUR 
wal - EUR 
wal_E - EUR 
war - EUR 
war_P - EUR 
wbq - EUR 
wbq_I - EUR 
wbr - EUR 
wbr_I - EUR 
wls - EUR 
wls_W - EUR 
wo_La - EUR 
wtm - EUR 
wtm_I - EUR 
xav - EUR 
xav_B - EUR 
xh - EUR 
xh_LS - EUR 
xh_ZA - ZAR 
xnr - ZAR 
xnr_I - ZAR 
xog - ZAR 
xog_U - ZAR 
xsl - ZAR 
xsl_C - ZAR 
xsr - ZAR 
xsr_N - ZAR 
yao - ZAR 
yao_M - ZAR 
yap - ZAR 
yap_F - ZAR 
yi - ZAR 
yi_UA - ZAR 
yo - ZAR 
yo_BJ - ZAR 
yo_NG - NGN 
yua - NGN 
yua_M - NGN 
za - NGN 
za_CN - NGN 
zdj - NGN 
zdj_K - NGN 
zea - NGN 
zea_N - NGN 
zh_CN - CNY 
zh_Ha - CNY 
zh_HK - HKD 
zh_TW - TWD 
zmi - TWD 
zmi_M - TWD 
zu - TWD 
zu_LS - TWD 
zu_MW - TWD 
zu_MZ - TWD 
zu_SZ - TWD 
zu_ZA - ZAR
```

Answer (score 2):

For your specific question, you can first convert the 3 letter ISO 4217 currency code to a 2 letter ISO 3166-1 alpha-2 country code and match the country code against a list of POSIX locales, recognizing that multiple locales with multiple languages may match.

For your more general question, why do you want to set the locale based on currency? One currency can map to many locales and languages, and also a person in a single locale may want to look at different currencies. While `es_US` is a supported locale, there may be other combinations that are not. Would it not be better to have them set independently?

**Mapping of Currency to Country Codes**

To convert ISO 4217 currency codes to ISO 3166 country codes, you can use the Open Knowledge Foundation conversion tables referenced below which come in JSON and CSV format:

HTML: http://data.okfn.org/data/core/country-codes

JSON: http://data.okfn.org/data/core/country-codes/r/country-codes.json

CSV: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/datasets/country-codes/master/data/country-codes.csv

**POSIX Locales List**

To convert ISO 3166 country codes to POSIX Locales, you can use a locale list to find locales with matching country codes. A list of locales is available in the following location on Linux systems:

```
/usr/share/i18n/SUPPORTED
```

This has also been posted to StackOverflow here:

[List of All Locales and Their Short Codes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3191664/list-of-all-locales-and-their-short-codes)

**More Information**

ISO Currency Codes: http://www.iso.org/iso/home/standards/currency_codes.htm