# Serving Angular app using Express

Tags: angularjs, node.js, express

I'm building an Angular app served using Express on Node.

What I'd like to do is when the user visits the site, append their locale to the url (domain.com/en-gb).

Then regardless of what locale they have specified serve up the same index.html.

```
app.use('/', function(req, res) {
   res.sendFile(__dirname + '/public/index.html');
});
```

The problem I'm having is working out how to serve up the same file regardless of request, but allowing assets such as images to not be rerouted to index.html as well?

Thanks,
Harry

Comment: Make sure you have a fallback, [there are some unusual locales out there](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3191729/393219)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you add a `use` statement like the following one, you specify the location for your images:

```
var staticPathImages = __dirname + '/assets/images';
app.use(express.static(staticPathImages));
```

express will serve those static assets directly, without re-routing to `index.html`...

Comment: I've got it setup like this:

    var staticPathImages = __dirname + '/public/assets';

    app.use(express.static(staticPathImages));

    app.use('/', function(req, res) {
      res.sendFile(__dirname + '/public/index.html');
    }); 

But it's still serving index.html for every file, any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: The answer is "yes"... :-) Are you sure if you request `localhost:3000/public/assets/image.jpg` (or the like), index.html file is served? It sounds quite strange... I have a setup similar to yours, and it works great... :-)

Comment: Did you relaunch your server? Maybe it's running your old code

Comment: Got it working finally, just had to correct the path! Thanks for your help! :)

Answer (score 2):

MarcoS answer is the correct one, I'll just add a more detailed description :

```
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public'))); //this line enables the static serving in the public directory
```

your `public` directory could be the following :

```
public 
|_css
|_js
|_images
  |_logo.png
```

Then, if you want to get an image :

```
http://localhost:3000/images/logo.png
```

And if you want to show it in your html page :

```
<img id="logo" src="/images/logo.png"/>
```