# Change date format Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, datetime, laravel-5

I'm from Indonesia, and I want to show date with Indonesian language format but what I've got was English language format.

Example format was **23 march 2017** *(english)*

I want to get like this one **23 Maret 2017** *(Indonesia)* so the problem of mine is language.

Can you give me some idea ? this is my example code

```
<?php echo date("d F Y", strtotime($row->tanggal_pelaksanaan)); ?>
```

and

```
Tgl: @foreach ($tindak as $tindakan)
     {{ date("d F Y", strtotime($tindakan->target_verifikasi)) }}
     @endforeach
```

Please Kindly help me. thank you.

Comment: You could use strftime() function with correct locale.

Comment: use carbon library.

Comment: @Autista_z how to do that for example ??

Comment: @Gaurav if i use carbon i got local this time right ? cant convert from DB right ? or how to use ?

Comment: @ChristianusAndre using composer install carbon them go through with this link or in laravel you can use directly. [Carbon](http://carbon.nesbot.com/#gettingstarted)

Comment: @Gaurav the prob is how to use carbon format but take from DB ??

Comment: Add the following line to the aliases array in the config/app.php:

`'Carbon' => 'Carbon\Carbon'`
And you need to add use `Carbon`; every class where you want to use it.

`{{ $quotes->created_at->format('d m Y i');`

Comment: http://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. See if the locale is installed in your server.

   You can list all the locale in your server by issuing the command

   **`locale -a`**
2. Install your locale. Indonesian locale, I believe is **`id_ID`** by issuing the command. The list of locale is obtained from this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/28357857/5808894

   **`sudo locale-gen id_ID`**

   **`sudo update-locale`**
3. Set locale using the method [setlocale](http://php.net/manual/en/function.setlocale.php)

   **`setlocale(LC_TIME, 'id_ID');`**
4. Either use [Carbon](http://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/#api-localization) or [strftime](http://de.php.net/manual/en/function.strftime.php) to output the localized date

   **`strftime("%a %d %b %Y", strtotime(date('Y-m-d')))`**

   OR

   **`Carbon\Carbon::parse('23-03-2017 11:23:45')->formatLocalized('%A %d %B %Y');`**

   outputs **Kamis 23 Maret 2017**

Comment: if i use windows so what should i do ? where should i put setlcoale bro ?

Comment: setlocale is an php function. You mean how to install locale in Windows?

Comment: in step 1 and 2 it used sudo.. so should i use cmd ?

Comment: btw how can i use on blade ? strftime("%a %d %b %Y", strtotime(date('Y-m-d'))) on this <?php echo date("d F Y", strtotime($keluhan->tanggal)); ?>

Comment: `<?php echo strftime("%a %d %b %Y", strtotime($keluhan->tanggal)); ?>`

Comment: Here's a link to set locale in windows https://www.java.com/en/download/help/locale.xml

Comment: That's really help. thank you so much.. sorry for my bad :)

Comment: wait, why it still show Wed 05 Apr 2017 ? i've change my locale and do <?php echo strftime("%a %d %b %Y", strtotime($keluhan->tanggal)); ?>

Comment: Because the locale might not be installed on your system! The locale you are using must be installed on the system.

Comment: umm how to do that ?? sorry ask again

Comment: Please follow the link I've shared and try again

Comment: i've follow this java.com/en/download/help/locale.xml step by step and the locale has been changed on my system. but when i try to display its still on english. I see my DB, saved date format is like this 2017-04-05 (english) even i've change locale... is that something vrong brother ? pls guide me little more, sorry for this prob

Comment: May be you should open up a new question to find how to install locale in windows

Answer (score 2):

```
$dateName = Carbon::now()->locale('id')->isoFormat('LL'); //return 17 Mei 2020 

$dateName = Carbon::now()->locale('id')->isoFormat('LLLL');  //return Minggu, 17 Mei 2020 pukul 10.21
```

**Try this code**
and you can check on https://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/#api-localization

Answer (score 0):

Laravel Eloquent allows you format from the model so you can do

```
$model->created_at->format('Y-m-d')
```

To do this you should add

```
$protected $dates = [
    'created_at',
    'updated_at',
    // add other column names here that you want as Carbon Date
];
```

This will then mutate the columns to be a easily manipulated date object

see https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent-mutators#date-mutators for further details

Answer (score 0):

You cannot depends on server locale, because most of application was running on their own devices with their own locale format. You can installing the locale format for your own device but not for others because they have their locale timezone.

Use another method like:

```
{{ date('d-m-y', strtotime($example->start_date))}}
```

The code above will change

> yyyy-mm-dd

format to

> d-m-y
>
> 2019-05-01 to 01-05-19

Or

```
{{ date('l, d-m-y', strtotime($example->start_date))}}
```

**Ouput:**

> Friday, 01-05-2019

Hope it helps.