# Material DatePicker parses incorrectly if user write date in input

Tags: angular, angular-material

In my angular 4 project I am using some [matDatepicker](https://material.angular.io/components/datepicker/overview), It works correctly if I select a date from datepicker but if I write manually the date in the input field I see the date in an incorrect Locale.

I am following this: [github](https://github.com/angular/material2/issues/7823), but I only see correct locale when I chose the date and not if I write the date.
Is it possible that the locale is overwritten?

This is the date-adapter:

```
    /**
 * @license
 * Copyright Google LLC All Rights Reserved.
 *
 * Use of this source code is governed by an MIT-style license that can be
 * found in the LICENSE file at https://angular.io/license
 */

import {Inject, Injectable, Optional} from '@angular/core';
import {DateAdapter, MAT_DATE_LOCALE, MatDateFormats} from '@angular/material';
// Depending on whether rollup is used, moment needs to be imported differently.
// Since Moment.js doesn't have a default export, we normally need to import using the `* as`
// syntax. However, rollup creates a synthetic default module and we thus need to import it using
// the `default as` syntax.
// TODO(mmalerba): See if we can clean this up at some point.
import * as _moment from 'moment';
// import {default as _rollupMoment, Moment} from 'moment';
import 'moment/locale/fr';
import { Moment } from 'moment';

const moment = _moment; // _rollupMoment || _moment;


export const MOMENT_DATE_FORMATS: MatDateFormats = {
  parse: {
    dateInput: 'D/MM/YYYY'
  },
  display: {
    dateInput: 'DD/MM/YYYY',
    monthYearLabel: 'MMMM Y',
    dateA11yLabel: 'LL',
    monthYearA11yLabel: 'MMMM Y'
  }
};

/** Creates an array and fills it with values. */
function range<T>(length: number, valueFunction: (index: number) => T): T[] {
  const valuesArray = Array(length);
  for (let i = 0; i < length; i++) {
    valuesArray[i] = valueFunction(i);
  }
  return valuesArray;
}


/** Adapts Moment.js Dates for use with Angular Material. */
@Injectable()
export class MomentDateAdapter extends DateAdapter<Moment> {
  // Note: all of the methods that accept a `Moment` input parameter immediately call `this.clone`
  // on it. This is to ensure that we're working with a `Moment` that has the correct locale setting
  // while avoiding mutating the original object passed to us. Just calling `.locale(...)` on the
  // input would mutate the object.
  private _localeData: {
    firstDayOfWeek: number,
    longMonths: string[],
    shortMonths: string[],
    dates: string[],
    longDaysOfWeek: string[],
    shortDaysOfWeek: string[],
    narrowDaysOfWeek: string[]
  };

  constructor(@Optional() @Inject(MAT_DATE_LOCALE) dateLocale: string) {
    super();
    this.setLocale(dateLocale || moment.locale());
  }

  setLocale(locale: string) {
    super.setLocale(locale);

    let momentLocaleData = moment.localeData(locale);
    this._localeData = {
      firstDayOfWeek: momentLocaleData.firstDayOfWeek(),
      longMonths: momentLocaleData.months(),
      shortMonths: momentLocaleData.monthsShort(),
      dates: range(31, (i) => this.createDate(2017, 0, i + 1).format('D')),
      longDaysOfWeek: momentLocaleData.weekdays(),
      shortDaysOfWeek: momentLocaleData.weekdaysShort(),
      narrowDaysOfWeek: momentLocaleData.weekdaysMin(),
    };
  }

  getYear(date: Moment): number {
    return this.clone(date).year();
  }

  getMonth(date: Moment): number {
    return this.clone(date).month();
  }

  getDate(date: Moment): number {
    return this.clone(date).date();
  }

  getDayOfWeek(date: Moment): number {
    return this.clone(date).day();
  }

  getMonthNames(style: 'long' | 'short' | 'narrow'): string[] {
    // Moment.js doesn't support narrow month names, so we just use short if narrow is requested.
    return style == 'long' ? this._localeData.longMonths : this._localeData.shortMonths;
  }

  getDateNames(): string[] {
    return this._localeData.dates;
  }

  getDayOfWeekNames(style: 'long' | 'short' | 'narrow'): string[] {
    if (style == 'long') {
      return this._localeData.longDaysOfWeek;
    }
    if (style == 'short') {
      return this._localeData.shortDaysOfWeek;
    }
    return this._localeData.narrowDaysOfWeek;
  }

  getYearName(date: Moment): string {
    return this.clone(date).format('YYYY');
  }

  getFirstDayOfWeek(): number {
    return this._localeData.firstDayOfWeek;
  }

  getNumDaysInMonth(date: Moment): number {
    return this.clone(date).daysInMonth();
  }

  clone(date: Moment): Moment {
    return date.clone().locale(this.locale);
  }

  createDate(year: number, month: number, date: number): Moment {
    // Moment.js will create an invalid date if any of the components are out of bounds, but we
    // explicitly check each case so we can throw more descriptive errors.
    if (month < 0 || month > 11) {
      throw Error(`Invalid month index "${month}". Month index has to be between 0 and 11.`);
    }

    if (date < 1) {
      throw Error(`Invalid date "${date}". Date has to be greater than 0.`);
    }

    let result = moment({year, month, date}).locale(this.locale);

    // If the result isn't valid, the date must have been out of bounds for this month.
    if (!result.isValid()) {
      throw Error(`Invalid date "${date}" for month with index "${month}".`);
    }

    return result;
  }

  today(): Moment {
    return moment().locale(this.locale);
  }

  parse(value: any, parseFormat: string | string[]): Moment | null {
    if (value && typeof value == 'string') {
      return moment(value, parseFormat, this.locale);
    }
    return value ? moment(value).locale(this.locale) : null;
  }

  format(date: Moment, displayFormat: string): string {
    date = this.clone(date);
    if (!this.isValid(date)) {
      throw Error('MomentDateAdapter: Cannot format invalid date.');
    }
    return date.format(displayFormat);
  }

  addCalendarYears(date: Moment, years: number): Moment {
    return this.clone(date).add({years});
  }

  addCalendarMonths(date: Moment, months: number): Moment {
    return this.clone(date).add({months});
  }

  addCalendarDays(date: Moment, days: number): Moment {
    return this.clone(date).add({days});
  }

  toIso8601(date: Moment): string {
    return this.clone(date).format();
  }

  /**
   * Returns the given value if given a valid Moment or null. Deserializes valid ISO 8601 strings
   * (https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc3339.txt) and valid Date objects into valid Moments and empty
   * string into null. Returns an invalid date for all other values.
   */
  deserialize(value: any): Moment | null {
    let date;
    if (value instanceof Date) {
      date = moment(value);
    }
    if (typeof value === 'string') {
      if (!value) {
        return null;
      }
      date = moment(value, moment.ISO_8601).locale(this.locale);
    }
    if (date && this.isValid(date)) {
      return date;
    }
    return super.deserialize(value);
  }

  isDateInstance(obj: any): boolean {
    return moment.isMoment(obj);
  }

  isValid(date: Moment): boolean {
    return this.clone(date).isValid();
  }

  invalid(): Moment {
    return moment.invalid();
  }
}
```

In my **app.module**

```
import { MomentDateAdapter, MOMENT_DATE_FORMATS } from './shared/moment-date-adapter/moment-date-adapter';

{ provide: MAT_DATE_LOCALE, useValue: 'it-IT' },
{ provide: MAT_DATE_FORMATS, useValue: MOMENT_DATE_FORMATS },
{ provide: DateAdapter, useClass: MomentDateAdapter },
```

But still not working, this is the output:
[image: datepicker]

first one is selected date, second date is written

Comment: your MOMENT_DATE_FORMATS seems odd. Can you add an example of date who are parsed incorrectly?

Comment: import 'moment/locale/fr'; in his code

Answer (score 4):

I don't know what you're exactly trying to do there, but you don't need such an adapter to do that ... Create this first :

```
export const CUSTOM_DATE_FORMAT = {
  parse: {
    dateInput: 'DD/MM/YYYY',
  },
  display: {
    dateInput: 'DD/MM/YYYY',
    monthYearLabel: 'MMMM YYYY',
    dateA11yLabel: 'DD/MM/YYYY',
    monthYearA11yLabel: 'MMMM YYYY',
  },
};
```

Then, in your module (fr is mine, replace it with whatever you want) :

```
import { MatMomentDateModule, MomentDateAdapter } from '@angular/material-moment-adapter';


imports: [MatMomentDateModule],
providers: [
  {provide: DateAdapter, useClass: MomentDateAdapter},
  {provide: MAT_DATE_FORMATS, useValue: CUSTOM_DATE_FORMAT},
  {provide: MAT_DATE_LOCALE, useValue: 'fr-FR'}
]
```

Comment: For the Italian language do I have to use: `useValue: 'it'` ?

Comment: useValue: 'it-IT'

Comment: as @Pterrat said. You can find **[all the codes there](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3191664/list-of-all-locales-and-their-short-codes)**

Comment: Sorry but still not working, I have edited the question

Comment: Did you try using **my** custom date format ? Because we have the same format (france-Italy), and it works on my side ...

Comment: Yes I am using your `CUSTOM_DATE_FORMAT`, is there a way to debug it?

Comment: I don't know ... But here is a **[plunkr](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material2-issue-hovsjw?file=app/app.module.ts)** that you can test and compare to your project

Comment: Ok but do I need to put this code: `{provide: DateAdapter, useClass: MomentDateAdapter},
  {provide: MAT_DATE_FORMATS, useValue: CUSTOM_DATE_FORMAT},
  {provide: MAT_DATE_LOCALE, useValue: 'fr-FR'}` only in principal app.module? or in every module that use datepicker?

Comment: Personally I created a `SharedModule` that I import in every module, that sets up all the material stuff (like the dates). I don't know your project, but you need to **make this setup on every module using the material date picker**.

Comment: Ok so my problem is that I imported it only in app.module

Comment: Well if your date picker is in app component, this isn't an issue !

Comment: another, question, now the Mat_DATE_LOCALE is hardcoded, but if I have a multilanguage application?

Comment: Inject this into your component : `private adapter: DateAdapter<any>`, and to change the locale, use `this.adapter.setLocale('fr-FR');`.

Comment: But it doesn't modify only the visualization? it modifies also the input parsing?

Comment: I don't know ... I took it from **[the documentation](https://material.angular.io/components/datepicker/overview#setting-the-locale-code)**, I actually never faced the case. But hey, DD/MM/YYYY is the best, keep that and don't mind changing :P

Answer (score 4):

I think you could add this in your module or your component.

```
providers: [
    {provide: MAT_DATE_LOCALE, useValue: 'fr-FR'},
    {provide: DateAdapter, useClass: MomentDateAdapter, deps: [MAT_DATE_LOCALE]},
    {provide: MAT_DATE_FORMATS, useValue: MAT_MOMENT_DATE_FORMATS},
  ],
```

When you change the input manually to the current locale format, it should be normally fine.

You can find an example in [the Angular Material documentation](https://material.angular.io/components/datepicker/overview#customizing-the-parse-and-display-formats).

You could use DateAdapter if you need to switch between Italian and other locales:

```
  constructor(private adapter: DateAdapter<any>) {}

  switchItalian() {
    this.adapter.setLocale('it');
  }

  switchFrench() {
    this.adapter.setLocale('fr');
  }
```