# Adding English language for Switzerland in Shopware

Tags: shopware

My question is about the localization in Shopware (5.3.4):
I want to add the English language for Switzerland country in my shop. In my backend I get an error when I want to add a new ISO entry. 
I tried both *Switzerland* and *Schweiz* as area.
Am I missing something ?
The error says :

> Save entry Entry " ()" could not be saved.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

It is only possible to create localizations known to the Zend framework. Pseudo-localizations cannot simply be created. You can simply use en_gb here, because the localization is only used for text modules and no other application in Shopware.

Please have a look at the locales: https://github.com/shopware/shopware/blob/5.4/engine/Library/Zend/Locale.php#L37

Comment: actually the local will be created, but what consequences has..that's another question

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that the form is failing to save the request sendet by you. See this link: [shopware 5.3.4 github](https://github.com/shopware/shopware/blob/7c271dbfb62cdbbeab4a728d48d108c8f5d67ee4/themes/Backend/ExtJs/backend/config/controller/form.js#L433)

```
    formStore.sync({
            success :function (records, operation) {
                message = me.messages.saveEntrySuccess;
                me.createGrowlMessage(record, title, message);
                store.load();
            },
            failure:function (batch) {
                message = me.messages.saveEntryError;
                if(batch.proxy.reader.rawData.message) {
                    message += '<br />' + batch.proxy.reader.rawData.message;
                }
                me.createGrowlMessage(record, title, message);
                store.load();
            }
});
```

To see more details of the problem you will have to activate the debug mode (see shopware documentation on how to do that).

For me it worked to add your locals (English -> Swizerland -> en_CH), however I wonder how will this help me further, because php doesn't recognize this local: [php locales list](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3191729/1595977)