# Not getting the right result for formating currency using MySql connector 5.1 with razor sql editor

Tags: mysql

I am getting wrong result while using FORMAT in my query .. I want to format the numbers into Indian currency I am following  right approach but its not working

Here is my query

```
select distinct FORMAT(sum(netamount), 'en_IN') as amount
from syncbill 
where cancelled<>'Y' and year(curdate())=year(billdate)
```

my value is as `netamount` is **27227004** after formatting it should show **2,72,27,004** but its showing **27,227,004**

I don't know where I am going wrong please guide me if anyone having knowledge here.
[image: Edited image]

this is i am getting while running this query

```
    select distinct FORMAT(sum(netamount), 0, 'en_IN') as amount 
from syncbill
where cancelled<>'Y' and year(curdate())=year(billdate)
```

Answer (score 2):

**This answer only applies to MySQL versions 5.5 and above.** The locale parameter to `FORMAT` was introduced in that version.

You forgot to specify the number of decimal places to [`FORMAT`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_format). Try this:

```
select distinct FORMAT(sum(netamount), 0, 'en_IN') as amount 
from syncbill
where cancelled<>'Y' and year(curdate())=year(billdate)
```

For example ([demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.3&fiddle=8718d160ae58ae793c3a39f01eb45de7)):

```
select  FORMAT(27227004, 0, 'en_IN')
```

Output

```
2,72,27,004
```

Comment: hey look i have edited the question  i have updated a image like what error i am getting i am using mySql 5.1 and rezor sql editor

Comment: Unfortunately your version of MySQL does not support the `locale` parameter to the `FORMAT` function, it was only introduced in version 5.5. See the [manual](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19078-01/mysql/mysql-refman-5.1/functions.html#function_format)

Comment: oohh kk so  thats the issue...so is there any alternative to that, i want to achieve that only in sql query end

Comment: I had a good look through the MySQL 5.1 manual and couldn't see any reference to locale formatting other than for dates. I think you're going to need to deal with it in your application.

Comment: @dheerajkumar Unfortunately I don't know Java. I suggest you post another question with a `java` tag, or searching google for `java currency format` seems to show up a few answers on SO. It's probably worth leaving this one as it might be useful to others, but you could delete it if you choose.

Comment: What is the use of 'en_IN'

Comment: @RahmanHaroon it is a locale selector that controls the number formatting, `en_IN` corresponds to `English (India)`. See for example https://stackoverflow.com/q/3191664/9473764

Comment: What will be the value by default..? If I pass FORMAT(27004, 4) like this (no en_IN)

Comment: @RahmanHaroon you can try things like that for yourself on sites such as dbfiddle.uk (the site linked to for my demo). But if the locale is not specified, it defaults to `en_US`, so `FORMAT(27004, 4)` will output `27,000.0000`