# How do I change the $ sign to ₱ in a textbox_leave action listener c#

Tags: c#

the default monetary sign for money is in $ sign, however I would like to somehow change it to a different currency. example like, ₱ or £.

here is my code as of the moment.

```
private void cash_Leave(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    double value;
    if(Double.TryParse(cash.Text, out value))
    {
        cash.Text = String.Format(System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture, "{0:C2}", value);
    }
    else
    {
        cash.Text = String.Empty;
    }
}
```

Comment: Side note: when dealing with currency, it's better to use `decimal`. Doing operations with floating-point numbers (such as `double`) can lead to some nasty rounding errors.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The ₱ sign stands for Philippine pesos, so you can just set the `CultureInfo` to the Philippine culture (en-PH):

```
String.Format(new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("en-PH"), "{0:C2}", value)
```

The £ sign stands for British Pounds, so you can use the culture info for Great Britain (en-GB) to get this symbol:

```
String.Format(new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("en-GB"), "{0:C2}", value)
```

See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3191729/5133585) for a list of locale codes.

Answer (score 0):

You have to change Currency Symbol for your Current Culture

i-e
do this before your code

```
var newCulture = System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.Clone() as CultureInfo;
newCulture.NumberFormat.CurrencySymbol = "₱";
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = newCulture;
```