# Ugly characters are returned for months février and décembre in html/php

Tags: php, html, utf-8

I am working on the php code below which returns the month names in french.

```
<script>
document.getElementById('title_fr').value = "<?php setlocale(LC_TIME, "fra"); echo strftime("%d %B %Y", strtotime( $this_date )); ?>";  
</script>
```

The above code returns the following months:

```
janvier
f�vrier
mars
avril
mai
juin
juillet
août
septembre
octobre
novembre
d�cembre
```

**Problem Statement:**

I am wondering what changes I need to make in the php code above so that it avoids question mark for `f�vrier` and `d�cembre`. It should return `février` and `décembre`

On head, I am using:

```
<meta charset="utf-8">
```

Comment: Make sure that _all_ the files you're using are saved in UTF-8. You can [check this answer out](https://stackoverflow.com/a/279279/2453432) for some more tips.

Comment: @deceze I tried your answer but it didn't work.

Comment: You tried *what exactly* and it did *what exactly*?

Comment: I tried this
setlocale(LC_TIME, "fra.UTF-8", "fra.utf8", "fra"); What is doing that now that its converting month names into english.

Comment: List your installed locales (as explained in the duplicate). See what locales you actually have at your disposal. If the required one isn't there, figure out how to add it for your system.

Comment: On following this tutorial https://sciex.com/support/knowledge-base-articles/how-to-check-operating-system-locale-on-windows-7-1460458252426  I tried the following command `systeminfo | findstr “Locale”` and it doesn't return anything.

Comment: Hmm, no idea how to do any of that on Windows. But https://stackoverflow.com/a/3191729/476 would suggest the correct locale may be `fr-FR`…

Answer (score 1):

Try with this:

```
setlocale (LC_TIME, 'fr_FR.utf8','fra');
```

Comment: It didn't work. What it is doing now that it is returning everything in English.