# How to display er after the 1st day of month in french in php?

Tags: php, html, date

I am working on a php code below which displays the month in php.

```
<script>
document.getElementById('title_fr').value = "<?php setlocale(LC_TIME, "frc"); echo strftime("%d %B %Y", strtotime( $this_date )); ?>"; 
</script>
```

The above php code returns month name in french as showm below.

```
janvier
février
mars
avril
mai
juin
juillet
août
septembre
octobre
novembre
décembre
```

**Problem Statement:**

I am wondering what changes I need to make in the php code above so that **For days of the month, if d = “1” then substitute “1er”**

I think I need to make some changes here `echo strftime("%d %B %Y", strtotime( $this_date ));` but I am not sure where exactly.

I added er after %d but it has added er after every day of the month.

Comment: Why? Is "1er" the french equivalent of "1st"? Why only the first day of the month?

Comment: @Sammitch The French word for "first" is "premier". I knew my 3 years of HS French would come in handy.

Comment: Then I'd just switch to `date()` or `DateTime()` where you can use `dS` for `1st`, `2nd`, `3rd`, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get the day number, and if it's `1` then append `er`.

```
<?php
setlocale(LC_TIME, "frc");
$this_time = strtotime( $this_date );
$day = date('d', $this_time);
$suffix = $day == 1 ? 'er' : '';
$formatted = strftime("%d$suffix %B %Y", $this_time);
?>
document.getElementById('title_fr').value = "<?php echo $formatted; ?>";
```

Comment: Thanks, it worked. I have one more [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55166190/ugly-characters-are-returned-for-months-f%C3%A9vrier-and-d%C3%A9cembre-in-html-php?noredirect=1#comment97073919_55166190), its not similar but I am still figuring out why its returning ugly characters.

Comment: Although, its marked as duplicate but the answer didn't help me much.

Comment: You need to set the HTML character set. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4696499/meta-charset-utf-8-vs-meta-http-equiv-content-type