# format currencies in a Vue component?

Tags: html, arrays, json, vue.js, vue-component

Good day everyone, I'm trying to format the value that JSON brings me in currency, I saw some suggestions but I still can't convert the value.
This is how I've my code structured

```
<template>
...
<div class="currency-selection">
   <input type="text" :value="conversionValue * cryptoQuantity " readonly />
...
<template>

<script>

export default {
    name: 'CurrencySelect',
    data: () => ({
        conversionValue: 0,
        cryptoQuantity: 1
}),
axios
            .get(
                "https://min-api.cryptocompare.com/data/price?fsym=btc&tsyms=COP"
            )
            .then((res) => {
                this.conversionValue = res.data.COP;
            })
            .catch((e) => {
                console.log(e);
            });
}
```

Right now the value is 169057977.17 but I want it to be displayed like this: 169.057.977,17

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `toLocaleString` to format numbers acording to the language and region you define.

Use `Number.toLocaleString('es-CO')` get this: `169.057.977,17`

See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3191729/3330981) for a list of supported locales

[See this example](https://sfc.vuejs.org/#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)

```html
<script>
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      conversionValue: 0,
      cryptoQuantity: 1
    }
  },
  async mounted () {
    this.conversionValue = await fetch("https://min-api.cryptocompare.com/data/price?fsym=btc&tsyms=COP").then(raw => raw.json()).then(json => json.COP)
  }
}
</script>

<template>
<input type="text" :value="(this.cryptoQuantity * this.conversionValue).toLocaleString('es-CO')"/>
</template>
```